# Center Align on a Absolutely Positioned Div

Tags: html, css, xhtml

```
div#thing {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

<div id="thing">
   <p>text text text with no fixed size, variable font</p>
</div>
```

The div is at the top, but I can't center it with `<center>` or `margin: 0 auto`;

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Your problem may be solved if you give your `div` a fixed width, as follows:

```
div#thing {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    width:400px;
    margin-left:-200px;
    left:50%;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that, even though we use the same technique for vertical centering all the time...

Thanks anyway, you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: what if the user has vertically scrolled down the div appears on the top of page while it should appear on the visible area

Comment: I am displaying thumbnails of dynamically reszied images in my overlay div, so I don't know the width.

Comment: this is only a workaround, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div appears to be the solution

Comment: This is not right answer. Different media type will not support this snippet.

Comment: Set width and margin-left in percentage to make it responsive. `width: 80%; margin-left: -40%`

Comment: Note that this works because you move the div to "start" from the center by 'Left: 50%;' and then u adjust to the left by using margin-left that amounts to half of your actual width. Genius, I would say.

Comment: it you are using a fixed width, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 100):

```
div#thing
{
    position: absolute;
    width:400px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: How does this work?  Can you please provide why your answer is valid?

Comment: I really like this method over others 99% of the time, you don't have to deal with padding, borders, etc. I've never seen this fail, next time provide an example if it fails for you.

Comment: Cool thing about this solution is that it works with percents too, just not sure if it's cross-browser compatible

Comment: Wow. I was not expecting this to work but it worked for me like a charm

Comment: Add in `bottom:0;` and you can centre the footer of the page...exactly was I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: if you remove the position, right and left property, the div element will basically in the centered. The thing is that you can't use margin:auto if you start adjusting the position of the element. But reading the question, I don't understand whe he need to position the element as absolute.

Comment: @dav: "[setting the value for left/right] specifies how far a box's (…) margin edge is offset to the (…) edge of the box's containing block." http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props

Comment: The beauty of this one is that you don't need to know the width.

Comment: I agree that this should be the correct answer, a -200px margin screams hack to me.

Comment: This works way better than the selected answer, as it is much more versatile.

Comment: Agree, this is much better, however I did use margin: 0 auto 0 auto; though. But good soln.

Comment: This is the (Best Answer)

Comment: The trick is setting both `left: 0;` and `right: 0;` anchors, then it can look like `horizontal-center` alignment (I was searching for something similar for `react-native`, and using `top: 0; bottom: 0;', I was able to `stretch` the component, and made it look like `vertical-center` alignment using `justifyContent: 'center'`)

Answer (score 40):

I know I'm late to the party, but I thought I would provide an answer here for people who need to horizontally position an absolute item, when you don't know its exact width.

Try this:

```
// Horizontal example.
div#thing {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

The same technique can also be applied, for when you might need vertical alignment, simply by adjusting the properties like so:

```
// Vertical example.
div#thing {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Whaaat. This is awesome! Could you explain how it works? Edit: Did some hunting and it seems like the left: 50% moves the div's left location to the center, which isn't really center. But the translateX shifts it back 50% of the **content's width**

Comment: The absolute positioning will position from the top left of an item. Using translate will shift it to the amount relative to its size.

Comment: Michael, just wanted you to know, you weren't late to the party bud...and for those who dont know:  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); does both the vertical and horizontal centering with 1 line

Answer (score 6):

To center it both vertically and horizontally do this:

```
div#thing {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.contentBlock {
    width: {define width}
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and my limitation was that i cannot have a predefined width. If your element does not have a fixed width, then try this

```
div#thing 
{ 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0px; 
  z-index: 2; 
  left:0;
  right:0;
 }

div#thing-body
{
  text-align:center;
}
```

then modify your html to look like this

```
<div id="thing">
 <div id="thing-child">
  <p>text text text with no fixed size, variable font</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use relative units, e.g.

```
#thing {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50vw;
    right: 25vw;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is necessary for you to have a relative width (in percentage), you could wrap your div in a absolute positioned one:

```
div#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Remember that in order to position an element absolutely, the parent element must be positioned relatively.

Answer (score -22):

Yes:

```
div#thing { text-align:center; }
```

Comment: This will align the contents within a div. It will not align the div in the center of the page. It will also not align an absolutely positioned div in any way other than the contents within it that are part of the document flow.