# css/ jQuery - center absolute positioned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The div is 50% opaque and is displayed on top of the site's content, and it has a fixed width of 960 pixels (it's created by jQuery).

How can I center it horizontally?

`margin: 0 auto;` doesn't work :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto;` won't work for elements that are absolutely positioned. Instead, we can work with the properties of the element itself. Check out the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/HnzyT/2/

To center it horizontally is easy since you know the width **AND** its positioned absolutely. All you have to do is give it 2 CSS properties:

```
width: 960px;
position: absolute;

/* ... other CSS properties... */

left: 50%; /* 1. move it to the right 50% of the width of the page; now the left side of the element is exactly in the middle */
margin-left: -480px; /* move the element to the left exactly half of its width and now the center of the element is centered horizontally */
```

If you want to center it both vertically and horizontally, you need to know how wide **AND** how tall the element is.

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Comment: thanks! I found another way: make the absolute div 100%, and put inside it a relative div with `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: @Alex... sure, but then you'd need another `<div>` element! if you want more markup, that's fine, as long as you got what you're looking for :)

Comment: I like this solution better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div You don't have to know the size.

Answer (score 12):

Just subtract the window midpoint from half the width of you element on resize.  Here's a simple plugin that you could easily accomodate to center vertically if need be as well:

```
$.fn.centerMe = function () {
    this.css('left', $(window).width()/2 - $(this).width()/2);
};

$(window).resize(function() { $('#yourElem').centerMe(); });

$('#yourElem').centerMe();
```

[**See working example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/86GT5/)