# jQuery: How to animate a centered div to fill the screen while its still being centered?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to animate a div to fill the screen and then return to its original size again. However, when i make the div fill the screen it doesn't animate from the centre, it starts from the top right. Furthermore, when I minimize it, it doesn't return to the starting position but to the top left.

I have the [jsfiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/deztructicus/QSwTn/3/). I'm trying to get it to animate smoothly from its starting point at the centre, fill the screen and then backwards to its starting position like in the begining.

Comment: Before the animation your div is already in the top-left corner, why do you change its style like that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method without the extra div used by pinouchon. [jsFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/kuYaK/3/):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var isFullscreen = false;

            function fullscreen(){      
                var d = {};
                var speed = 900;
                if(!isFullscreen){ // MAXIMIZATION
                    d.width = "100%";
                    d.height = "100%"; 
                    isFullscreen = true;
                    $("h1").slideUp(speed);
                }
                else{ // MINIMIZATION            
                    d.width = "300px";
                    d.height = "100px";            
                    isFullscreen = false;
                    $("h1").slideDown(speed);
                }
                $("#controls").animate(d,speed);            
            }

        </script> 
        <style> 
            #controls{
                width:300px;
                height:100px;
                margin: auto auto auto auto;
            }   
            body, html{
                height:100%;
            }

        </style> 

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align=center> Header (To be covered on Fullscreen) </h1>
        <div id='controls' style="background-color:green;" align="center">
            <input type='button' value='fullscreen' onclick='fullscreen();' />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that your moving div has always `position: relative;`, and contained in a div with `position: absolute;`, and that he is centered [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div)

Here is a working example of what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/FP2DZ/.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var isFullscreen = false;

            function fullscreen(){

                var d = {};
                var speed = 900;
                if(!isFullscreen){ // MAXIMIZATION

                    d.width = "100%";
                    d.height="100%";                    
                    d.left="0%";
                    d.top="0%";
                    d.marginLeft="0px";

                    $("#controls").animate(d,speed);
                    isFullscreen = true;

                }else{ // MINIMIZATION

                    d.width="300px";
                    d.height="100px";
                    d.left="50%";
                    d.top="50%";
                    d.marginLeft="-150px";


                    $("#controls").animate(d,speed);
                    isFullscreen = false;
                }

            }

        </script> 
        <style>
            #controls{
                width:300px;
                height:100px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -150px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align=center> Header (To be covered on Fullscreen) </h1>
        <div id='controls' style="background-color:green;" align="center">
            <input type='button' value='fullscreen' onclick='fullscreen();' />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I guess I was a bit late ;)