# keep aspect ratio for image and have centered text overlay

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a row of blocks with background images and centered text overlay them. I want to maintain aspect ratio (16:9) and keep the text vertically centered. Is there any way to do this?  I don't want to use `background-image` and  `background-size: cover;` because I'm animating the background on hover. I know that'd be much easier ... but it's no fun doing easy things.

This is what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/kezid/1/edit

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to use a background-image? The image is clearly styling (it serves as a background), so does not belong in your content but in your css. That should be your first rule, not what is easy or not. And backgrounds can be animated just as well...

Comment: can you animate opacity on background? And the image will actually be related to the content.

Comment: I solved it with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508275/how-to-center-a-position-absolute-element