# center div reloaded: 50% of what?

Tags: css

Within here I found the following solution for centering a `div` within another `div`:

```
.centerSplash {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

So far, that works fine with FF.

In IE(9) it looks like this

```
   ----------------------------------------------------------
            |                                |  (-50% height to top of 
            +--------------------------------+               the outer div)
```

whereas Chrome shows:

```
          ----------------------------------------------------------


          center of outer div              
          ----------->  +--------------------------------+
                        |                                |
                        |                                | 
                        +--------------------------------+
```

Does anyone have a solution *CSS based*, non jQuery, non JS and no table cells (that's all I already found here ....).

**[edit]**

just copied the relevant [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/60urvv2L/1/)

Comment: At first glance, the `margin-right` property seems pointless in this case, also giving it a right margin of `-50%` won't align it to center. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508275/how-to-center-a-position-absolute-element/25776315#25776315

Comment: @RishabhShah Small code like this don't need fiddle, you can do it yourself : http://jsfiddle.net/9zmo881b/

Comment: keep in mind that every browser has a default "user-agent" styling which it applies to some elements unless overridden by you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div

Comment: @karan3112 Actually [it *does*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: chrome displays this fine by me in the fiddle which the OP posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this technique

CSS

```
.centerSplash {
       position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
               /*Add this*/
        left: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto; 
}
```

This works only if the `width` is specified.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/60urvv2L/2/)