# Why my overlay div is not centering

Tags: css

I am sure it is a "simple" for the pros:

I am at lost on how to center (horizontally and vertically) the **overlay** to its parent. Please see the jsfiddle link for the details.

Thank you in advance for your time...

LB

```
<div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
        <!-- 1st row */ -->
        <div class="child">1-1</div>
        <div class="child">1-2</div>
        <div class="child">1-3</div>

        <!-- 2nd row */ -->
        <div class="child">2-1</div>
        <div class="child">2-2</div>
        <div class="child">2-3</div>

        <!-- 3rd row */ -->
        <div class="child">3-1</div>
        <div class="child">3-2</div>
        <div class="child">3-3</div>


        <div class="overlay">
            Overlaysdfds 
            line2sdf sdfdsf sdfsdf sfdsdf
            <P />line 3
         </div> 

    </div>


</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
<style>
.grandparent {
    posttion: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    max-width:600px;

    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.parent {
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
    padding:20px;
    verflow:hidden;
}
.parent:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.child {
    posttion: relative;
    float:left;
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 22%; 
    margin:1.66%;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top:-100px;
    color: white; background: #666666; opacity: .8;
    z-index: 1000;
}
<style>
```

Here is the link to the example

```
http://jsfiddle.net/lb6688/aj7udvsq/3/
```

Again, appreciate your time!!!

Comment: There's invalid markup in your html: <p />

Comment: I'm surprised by the number of times that this same question is asked on Stack Overflow and how people still ask it. It proves little to no research before posting. If you search on Google "stack overflow center element vertically and horizontally" (without the quotes), you get over 1.5 million results! And it would have taken less time that posting the question and creating the fiddle... shrug

Comment: This is a complete different question IMHO !!!

Comment: How is it different? The answers that you got for this question work for your problem, and they are the same as the ones in the question that Hashem suggested (e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25776315/3695983). Your code may be different, but the essence of the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: I see your point. Thanks, I will try harder next time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)` to center the element within the parent (instead of hard coding values for the margin-top and margin-left):

```
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white; background: #666666; opacity: .8;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/aj7udvsq/4/

Comment: Thanks for helping and your comments. I need the overlay vertically centered within it's parent. Any suggestions?

Comment: I do appreciate your help !!!

Comment: @LittleBrother: Add `position:relative;` to the parent along with the indicated `transform:translate(-50%, -50%);` in the overlay and it will work. Fixed the JSFiddle (I realized that there was some  invalid styles: `posttion: relative;` or `verflow:hidden;`), and now it works the way it should: http://jsfiddle.net/aj7udvsq/6/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the changes at the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/w4boh5mg/1/

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
    max-width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    color: white; background: #666666; opacity: .8;
}

  .parent {
    position: relative; /* or absolute */
    margin: 5%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I need the overlay vertically centered within it's parent. I am always struggling with "centering" elements