# How to center div vertically inside of absolutely positioned parent div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, absolute

I am trying to get blue container in the middle of pink one, however seems `vertical-align: middle;` doesn't do the job in that case.

```
<div style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;">
    <div style="text-align: left; position: absolute;height: 56px;vertical-align: middle;background-color: pink;">
        <div style="background-color: lightblue;">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Expectation:

[image]

Please suggest how can I achieve that.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqmp1z9m/)

Comment: Is there a reason why are you using `position: absolute` everywhere?

Comment: the `vertical-align: middle;` works with `display: inline-block` or table layout

Comment: check this link: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ ;)

Comment: @Vucko yes - that is prerequisite as this is just simplified version of very complex layout, but absolute position in both top divs is key thing.

Comment: @Vladimirs I can only think of `margin-top: calc((56px - 16px) / 2)`, where `56px - parent height`, `16px - element height/font-size` - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcsc6ey6/)

Comment: @Vucko thanks, but problem is that `test` text changes dynamically and it might be more than in one line so that seems requires some javascript, but I am looking for css-only solution.

Comment: Can you expain why and the needs , you inbricate 2 elements in absolute position ?

Answer (score 510, accepted):

First of all note that `vertical-align` is only applicable to table cells and inline-level elements.

There are couple of ways to achieve vertical alignments which may or may not meet your needs. However I'll show you [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508275/how-to-center-a-position-absolute-element/25776315#25776315) [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474) from my favorites:

## 1. Using `transform` and `top`

```css
.valign {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity */
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;">
    <div style="text-align: left; position: absolute;height: 56px;background-color: pink;">
        <div class="valign" style="background-color: lightblue;">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The key point is that a percentage value on `top` is relative to the `height` of the containing block; While a percentage value on `transform`s is relative to the size of the box itself (the bounding box).

If you experience [font rendering issues](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2014/05/04/fixing-typography-inside-of-2-d-css-transforms/) (blurry font), the fix is to add `perspective(1px)` to the `transform` declaration so it becomes:

```
transform: perspective(1px) translateY(-50%);
```

It's worth noting that CSS `transform` [is supported in IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility).

## 2. Using `inline-block` (pseudo-)elements

In this method, we have two sibling `inline-block` elements which are aligned vertically at the middle by `vertical-align: middle` declaration.

One of them has a `height` of `100%` of its parent and the other is our desired element whose we wanted to align it at the middle.

```css
.parent {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: pink;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0; /* remove the gap between inline level elements */
}

.dummy-child { height: 100%; }

.valign {
    font-size: 16px; /* re-set the font-size */
}

.dummy-child, .valign {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="dummy-child"></div>
        <div class="valign" style="background-color: lightblue;">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, we should use one of the [available methods to remove the gap between inline-level elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements).

Comment: Thanks for this useful tips. It was working for my project. Good works.

Comment: For the first method `valign` element should be `display: block`

Comment: `transform: translateY(-50%);` Never seen this before, but it works flawlessly. Real life saver.

Comment: Now we can finally ditch support for IE8, the `translateY` approach has universal cross-browser support.

Answer (score 104):

use this :

```
.Absolute-Center {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

refer this link: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Comment: How isn't this the main solution? So easy and it works!

Comment: Keep in mind that `height` property must be defined (in px, em, etc.) for this to work.

Comment: What if I have multiple divs inside the parent? wouldn't all be all placed on top of each other?

Comment: it doesn't work if there's one more child on the same level with "absolute-center"

Comment: How in 10 years of programming I haven't use this before? =D Thanks

Comment: This did not work in my case. For me it worked like this: `.absolute_element { top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); }`

Answer (score 29):

Use flex blox in your absoutely positioned div to center its content.

See example https://plnkr.co/edit/wJIX2NpbNhO34X68ZyoY?p=preview

```
.some-absolute-div {    
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;

  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Yes, flexbox is the way to go in 2021! Although make sure to use `top: 0; bottom: 0; left:0; right 0;` so that first its dimensions become same as that of relatively positioned parent div, and then magic of flexbox kicks in!

Answer (score 24):

Center vertically and horizontally:

```
.parent{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.c{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

For only vertical center

```html
    <div style="text-align: left; position: relative;height: 56px;background-color: pink;">
        <div style="background-color: lightblue;position:absolute;top:50%;    transform: translateY(-50%);">test</div>
    </div>
```

I always do like this, it's a very short and easy code to center both horizontally and vertically

```css
.center{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="center">Hello Centered World!</div>
```

Comment: This answer has already been given in the accepted answer.

Comment: That mean's i can't add any new things here @TaylerH

Comment: There are plenty of other questions asked each day in [tag:html] or [tag:css] for you to try and answer. You should only post an answer if you can add something new to any existing answers. Repetition of content doesn't help anyone.

Comment: I think this one is the perfect and easiest solution.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT: 10/22** as nowdays, `display` `flex` or `grid` is widely implemented i would suggest to use one or the other *(`display:table`/`table-cell` will still work if you need compatibility with old or exotic browsers , like my TV...)*

- flex

```css
.a{
   position: absolute; 
  left: 50px; 
  top: 50px;
}
.b{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 56px;
}
.c {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
/* move the flex demo aside */
.a.b{left:100px}
```

```html
You even need less markup
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">test</div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="a b">
    <div class="c">test</div>
  </div>
```

- grid (similar at that point)

```css
.a{
   position: absolute; 
  left: 50px; 
  top: 50px;
}
.b{
  display:grid;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 56px;
}
.c {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

/* move the grid  demo aside */
.a.b{left:100px}
```

```html
You even need less markup
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">test</div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="a b">
    <div class="c">test</div>
  </div>
```

---

**Original answer 02/2015** (still efficient everywhere) *use with very old or exotic browsers not implementing yet flex or grid*

You may use `display:table`/`table-cell;`

```css
.a{
   position: absolute; 
  left: 50px; 
  top: 50px;
  display:table;
}
.b{
  text-align: left; 
  display:table-cell;
  height: 56px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: pink;
}
.c {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div  class="b">
    <div class="c" >test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your example works perfect, however `.b` missing `position: absolute;` which is important to get other things displayed property which I not included to keep code clearer. I know that makes no sense having table-cell absolutely positioned but maybe there is another approach that will allow to retain `position: absolute;` in both `.a` and `.b` classes?

Comment: if a is absolute position, and b (the child)  giving it it's size, b is itself in absolute position towards the rest of the content. unless a is suppose to remain unsized i do not understand the purpose  of absolute inside absolute ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple way using Top object.

eg: If absolute element size is 60px.

```
.absolute-element { 
    position:absolute; 
    height:60px; 
    top: calc(50% - 60px);
}
```

Comment: Using `calc` is helpful, though this should be `top: calc(50% - 30px)` for it to actually be centered.

Answer (score 2):

An additional simple solution

HTML:

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

---

CSS:

```
#d1{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;left:100px;
}

#d2{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:50px; width:50px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `display:table;` in parent div and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` in child div

```html
<div style="display:table;">
      <div style="text-align: left;  height: 56px;  background-color: pink; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
          <div style="background-color: lightblue; ">test</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it's possible that your answer is good but you can improve it very much by adding some description of what your code does...

Answer (score 1):

ok thought i would add the following

it centers an element in an absolutely positioned div without adding additional css to the parent, the solution is contained entirely within the element to be centered

```css
#view {
      position          : absolute;
      inset             : 0 0 0 0;
}

.center {
      display           : flex;
      align-items       : center;
      justify-content   : center;
      width             : 100%;
      height            : 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id=view>

      <div class=center>
            center
      </div>
  
</div>
```

the width,height 100% is required, [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) centers vertically, [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) centers horizontally

a post on this thread suggests adding text-align center helps with overflowing text, i haven't tested this

Answer (score 0):

in my case,

```
   centered-vertically {
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
  }
```

worked

Answer (score 0):

The much simpler way for to center position absolute items vertically and horizontally to the screen is to use "inset" property.

```css
.center-horizontally-vertically{
      position: absolute;
      inset: 0;
      margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-horizontally-vertically">
 Test
</div>
```

inset property sets left,right,top and bottom properties to 0 at once.