# Push element to 50% of parent's height

Tags: html, css

```css
.qty_wrap{
  height:100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 999; margin: 0 auto; bottom: 0" class="qty_wrap">
        <select>
          <option>Blue</option>
          <option selected>Green</option>
          <option>Red</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

I want to push my `select` element to center vertically.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28455100/3597276

Comment: likely duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flexbox with `align-items` set to `center`.

```css
.qty_wrap {
  height: 100px;
  background: silver;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="qty_wrap">
  <select>
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option selected>Green</option>
    <option>Red</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

It is not clear why you set the container to `position:absolute`, if that is only for making it the same width as the `select` box, you can actually achieve that by using `display:inline-flex`.

```css
.qty_wrap {
  height: 100px;
  background: silver;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="qty_wrap">
  <select>
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option selected>Green</option>
    <option>Red</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**for future:** Using `transform` with `top: 50%` is another solution. if you don't like to use `new attributes` like `flex`.

```css
.qty_wrap{
  height:100px;
  background: red;
}

select {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 999; margin: 0 auto; bottom: 0" class="qty_wrap">
        <select>
          <option>Blue</option>
          <option selected>Green</option>
          <option>Red</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```