# Bootstrap Vertical Align Image

Tags: html, image, css, vertical-alignment

On this website: http://www.livenews.surf/ I want to make news images and text vertically middle align, how i can do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28456704/1816407

Comment: Please, attach some of the target code to your question. If the site of the link happens to disappear (or just changes its content), there will be no reference of what's going on.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use Flexbox (see spec. for more details on it's usage).

For this particular case, assign a custom class to each of your content containing div (currently it only has `.col-md-11`), for example class "content" and add this code to your stylesheet

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Small code explanation: `align-items` aligns the items vertically, since we left the default flex direction which is row and `flex-wrap` will allow our parent container to wrap children to next line (default is `nowrap`).

Keep in mind, that **I haven't included vendor prefixes** for the sake of this answer, however I would strongly recommend you to do so, using a tool such as Autoprefixer.

Comment: See answer below for bootstrap 4

Answer (score 83):

Use the following classes in your containing `div.row` instead of custom CSS as suggested for bootstrap 4.

`d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center`

Answer (score 5):

Well, As you are using bootstrap columns, so you will need to make by following a couple of steps as explained below:

As a general case html structure of your web page is as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-11">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/image.jgp">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
           // text goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

First of all you will need to make the height of both columns (image + text) same. For this you can use jQuery [matchHeight](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/).
After that you can make your images vertically centered with the help of following change.

```
<div class="col-md-5 photo">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/image.jgp">
    </a>
</div>

.photo {
    display: table;
}
.photo a {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
.photo img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/3U3PAz1DNjt6XfR6bmNX?p=preview).

Comment: Are you sude `col-md-5` should be directly under `col-md-11`? Afaik that's not how bootstrap works. You need at least a `row` in-between.

Comment: @Eric You are right. I've corrected the template. Thanks for highlighting the issue.