# Text in Bootstrap progress bar is clipped

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem with bootstrap's progress bar. The span text I want displayed inside is only showing the bottom half and I can't figure out why.

I am doing a code along with my course and I have checked it thoroughly and can't see any difference in the code.

Our IDEs are different. He's using cloud9 and I am using codeanywhere. I wouldn't have thought that would matter.

I tried to continue with the code along and add CSS thinking it might sort it out. But the problem persisted

**Code Snippet**

```css
.progress {
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.progress-type {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 3px 30px 2px 10px;
  color: #fafafa;
  background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:90%;">
        <span class="sr-only">90% Complete</span>
      </div>
      <span class="progress-type">HTML / HTML5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Bootstrap 5.3 -->

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Bootstrap or height problem. It's a matter of how you're centering your absolutely positioned element. (The parent of such an element does not expand to contain it, per HTML spec.) Use a more standard method for that (not padding) and it's fine.

[How to center div vertically inside of absolutely positioned parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28455100/1264804)

```css
.progress-type {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%; /* put the top edge half way down */
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* shift the text up half its height */
  padding: 0 30px 0 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fafafa;
  background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="progress position-relative">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:90%;">
          <span class="sr-only">90% Complete</span>
        </div>
        <span class="progress-type">HTML / HTML5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if I override Bootstrap and force the height using `!important`.

```css
.progress {
  position: relative;
  height: 25px !important;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.progress-type {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 3px 30px 2px 10px;
  color: #fafafa;
  background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:90%;">
        <span class="sr-only">90% Complete</span>
      </div>
      <span class="progress-type">HTML / HTML5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Bootstrap 5.3 -->

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The two text strings are not vertically aligned with this method. It's better to center them dynamically.

Comment: The question implies he's getting different results from someone else, so I determined a reason why that might be the case. I don't know why Bootstrap is taking precedence, since the selector doesn't seem any more specific, but the !important will work around that. I'm addressing the question "why do I get different results from the other person", rather than "what's the best way to do this", in order to be minimally invasive.

Comment: Fair enough. I suspect code differences, so I ignored that aspect of the question. IDE doesn't matter, and Bootstrap and HTML are standardized enough these days that browser shouldn't matter either.

Comment: The other guys CSS fixed the issue. Still not sure why it was happening when the CSS was commented out but if it works then I am not about to try and fix it.