# Unable to center div horizontally, position fixed involved

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that I want to center horizontally inside my browser window without changing the vertical position. Here's my div:

```
<div id="divErrorMessage" class="ErrorClientSide">
    <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: 6px;"></div>
    <div id="divErrorMessageText" style="margin-left: 6px;margin-top: 2px;">{ERROR MESSAGE HERE}</div>
    <img src="./Images/Icons/tinyx.png" style="position: absolute; top: 4px; right:4px; cursor:pointer" onclick="closeErrorMessage();" />
</div>
```

And here's the class:

```
.ErrorClientSide {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 4px;
  left: 370px;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
```

Note: I removed the color styles and such from the class above for brevity.

[Try it out here](http://test.fittrack.club/_div.html).
Instructions: Leave all boxes blank and just click the **Next >>** button. You should see a pink error message div appear at the top that says *"Error: All fields are required."*, but the horizontal positioning is way off.

Problem: I cannot center `divErrorMessage` horizontally in my browser window. I'm pretty sure that `position:fixed` is the problem, but if I remove that, my div disappears and I can't find it. `left:370px` is clearly a problem as well. If I remove that, the div aligns at the left of the browser and I can't find any way to center it.

Here are my only positioning requirements for this div:

1. It needs to be positioned vertically a little below the brown header at the top.
2. It needs to be horizontally centered in the browser window.

If CSS can't do this easily I would be happy for a jquery solution as well, but I'm guessing this should be easy with CSS.

**Important note: The error message div and much of the content is inside an iFrame.**

Comment: Will that div have a fixed width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the absolutely positioned error box doesn't have a fixed `width`, you could achieve the horizontal alignment by a combination of `left: 50%;` and `transform: translateX(-50%);`.

For instance:

```css
.ErrorClientSide {
  position: fixed;
  top: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

*Vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity.*

---

It's worth noting that `translate` transform [is supported in IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform). For further reading you could refer to the topic below:

- [How to center a "position: absolute" element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508275/how-to-center-a-position-absolute-element/25776315#25776315)

Comment: I like your answer if position must be fixed and no width - but I'm sort of wondering why there's a need for the position to be fixed in this case.

Comment: @MiaSno `fixed` value? it is not a must. As I noted, it works for *absolutely positioned* elements which includes elements with both `absolute` or `fixed` positioning values. Also it may work for `relative` positioning as well but if I remember correctly, Firefox has an issue where the parent element doesn't have an explicit `width` which is needed for percentage value on `left` to work.

Answer (score 0):

it actually is located outside the form - which means it's falling in the DOM below the form if position is not fixed.  If you want to not move it - you'll need a negative positioning top and a width sort of like this:

```
.ErrorClientSide {
display: block;
position: relative;
top: -319px;
width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your error div is using a fixed position, you should change its `left` and `margin-left` position accordingly.

Let's suppose this error div will have a width of 200px, you could adjust your CSS with the following change:

```
 .ErrorClientSide {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
 }
```

Your `margin-left` attribute should be the negation of half your div's width (for instance, if your div's width is 378px instead of 200px, you should use `margin-left: -189px;`).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your div has width: 100px, then you can do left: 50%; margin-left: -50px;

```
.ErrorClientSide {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Alternatively you can do:

```
.ErrorClientSide {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

This centre you div inside window

Answer (score 0):

Remove position, top and left and use margin: 0 auto and width. Modify the markup to put divErrorMessage before the form. Or wrap it with an absolute position div then center it inside of that.

But first, *please* don't use `<center>` as it's been deprecated.

Comment: This is basically what most would do - but sometimes people are working in a structure they can't change.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to position a DIV vertically and horizontally you have to wrap it in 3 divs.

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="middle">
<div class="inner">

<h1>The Content</h1>

<p>Once upon a midnight dreary...</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
display: table;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.middle {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
width: /*whatever width you want*/;
}
```

I pulled this answer from [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: Ahh sorry I did in fact misread. Thats what I get got staying up too late.