# How can I place my icon in the middle and center of my div?

Tags: html, css, icons, center

I am trying to place my icon in the **middle** and **center** of my div.
I've tried `text-align:center;`, and `vertical-align: middle;`

Also, I'm not sure why I can't place my text inside my right div.

Here is my : [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/6w1h177a/)

My result now :

[image]

Comment: Please kindly explain why you down-vote my question so I can learn. Thank-you.

Comment: The icons or the divs containing the icons?

Comment: The icon. I want it to be in the middle and center. Not just **center**.

Comment: Do not delete a fiddle or copy the code to here. This question is now useless to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `vertical-align` property is only applicable to inline-level elements and table-cells.

In this case, you could align the icons at the middle by setting a `line-height` to each `.tl-top` and `.tl-bot` divs — equal to their `height`s.

Also, in order to put the third div into the right section, you could position in `absolute`ly, relative to the main div and then align it properly by using a combination of `top`/`left` and `transform: translate()` function.

```css
.tl-box {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:239px;
    height:80px;
    margin:13.5px;
    position: relative;
}
.tl-box .tl-top {
    width:45px;
    height:39px;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#4e90cb;
    line-height: 39px;
}
.tl-box .tl-bot {
    width:45px;
    height:40px;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#4e90cb;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.tl-box .tl-right {
    width:194px;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(50% + 22px); /* where 22px is half of the width of the left box */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="tl-box">
    <div class="tl-top"> <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>

    </div>
    <div class="tl-bot"> <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>

    </div>
    <div class="tl-right">
        Put me in the right div
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Finally someone get my point ! Do you mind explain what you modified a little bit ? Rather than that, you owned this question. I'll make sure to accept when the timer is up. Thank you.

Comment: It's precisely clear. I'm trying to learn them right now. Especially, my right div one ?  Why is my situation is so complicated just to put a text inside my right div ? Again, I am just curious.

Comment: @rangerover.js Actually, there are couple of ways to achieve that layout. I just wanted to keep the current markup untouched. E.g. If the sizes are fixed, we could place the text into the main element and also add a proper padding-left to it and then position the left boxes `absolute`ly in proper positions at the left side.

Comment: @rangerover.js However, for the right div and the technique I've used, an explanation can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508275/how-to-center-a-position-absolute-element/25776315#25776315).

Answer (score 2):

A simple way could be to set the `icon` elements to be `table-cells` and the containing `divs` as `tables`:

```
i.fa {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   /* etc... */
}

.tl-box .tl-top {
  display:table;
  text-align:center;
  /* etc... */ 
} 

.tl-box .tl-bot {
  display:table;
  text-align:center;
  /* etc... */
}
```

**[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6w1h177a/4/)**

---

### Updated Solution

A slightly nicer way of organizing this could involve `flex`, `calc` etc.

[**jsFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/6w1h177a/7/)

**CSS:**

```
.tl-box {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:239px;
    height:80px;
    margin:13.5px; 
    display:flex;
} 

#left-column { 
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    border-right:1px solid black;
}

#main-content { 
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.icon-containers {
    height:50%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#4e90cb; 
}

.icon-containers:first-child {
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

i.fa {
    position:relative;
    top: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tl-box">
    <div id="left-column">
        <div class="icon-containers"> 
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>    
        </div>
        <div class="icon-containers"> 
            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="tl-right">Put me in the right div</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting answer ! How about my right div ? Can I throw any text in it ?

Comment: How complicate is it ? if I want to place the text in my right div using your approach ?

Comment: @rangerover.js I'll have a much better solution in a minute, just busy but about to do it