# margin: 0 auto is not working on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="carousel slide" data-ride = "carousel" style="position: relative">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                 <div class="item active">
                 <img src="images/slide-1.jpg">
                 </div>
                 <div class="item">
                 <img src="images/slide-2.jpg">
                 </div>
                 <div class="item">
                 <img src="images/slide-3.jpg">
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="background-color:#fff; top: 50px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

The problem is "container" div is not centering. I know the "position: absolute" is the main trouble maker but how can i position the div without "position: absolute"?  What is the solution?

Comment: in Bootstrap, `.container` class already has `margin:0 auto;` set by-default!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rahulchandrasekharan/22rooLr3/5/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center a "position: absolute" element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508275/how-to-center-a-position-absolute-element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following code for center..

```
.container{
  background-color:#fff; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50px; 
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

<div class="container">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `text-align: center;` for parent and `display: inline-block` for the child.It is that simple.For more info, check out [this medium article published by freecodecamp](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-center-things-with-style-in-css-dc87b7542689).

Answer (score 1):

you must define the width of parent div and container then you can use

```
margin:0 auto;
```

or 
if container's width is 70%

```
margin-left:15%; 
margin-right:15%;
```

15% = (100 - container's width) / 2