# Center position of current screen position

Tags: javascript

Is there an option to find center position (top and left) of an actual screen position?

My main goal is to show div in the center of the screen no matter where i scroll or click

Comment: And you are committed to using javascript/jquery for this? Or is a CSS-only solution valid as well?

Comment: I will answer with a question: what have you tried? If you google a bit you will find plenty of examples to start with. Then you can ask for help on your specific code

Comment: Yes, there's an option: calculate the center using window.screen - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen

Comment: FYI, pure css solution. http://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/JKgwvY

Comment: `$(window).height() - $('div.yourelement').height()) / 2` you can figure out width.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center a "position: absolute" element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508275/how-to-center-a-position-absolute-element)

Comment: please, only javascript. I've tried a lot of examples from google, non of them works.

Comment: by the way, the solution with pure css done by Moon is the best. Why don't use just css instead of javascript?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `window` attributes to get center coordinates in pure javascript:

```
var x = window.innerWidth / 2;
var y = window.innerHeight / 2;
```

Comment: nope. It gives only the size of my screen, not the actual position in document

Comment: not size, but half (thus the center). Use this to position the element you want...

Comment: Full code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64990003/8804293

Answer (score 1):

**With Jquery**

```js
jQuery.fn.center = function(parent) {
    if (parent) {
        parent = this.parent();
    } else {
        parent = window;
    }
    this.css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": ((($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop() + "px"),
        "left": ((($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
    });
return this;
}
$("div.target:nth-child(1)").center(true);
$("div.target:nth-child(2)").center(false);
```

```css
div.container{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #555;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}

div.target{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    color:white;
    background:rgba(30,30,30,.7);
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="target">1<br>parent</div>
    <div class="target">2<br>window</div>
</div>
```

**With Pure CSS**

```css
div {
  background:green;
  position:fixed;
  color:#fff;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: please, only javascript

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen

Answer (score 0):

please add these code to add center div in web page

```css
div {
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  color:#fff;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  padding:50px;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: please, only javascript

Answer (score 0):

Please tray this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
 var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
 var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
 $('.className').css({
  position: 'absolute',
  left: windowWidth / 2,
  top: windowHeight / 2
    }); 
  });
  // call `resize` to center elements
  $(window).resize();
});
```

```css
div {
  background:red;  
  color:#fff;  
  padding:50px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="className"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
div {
   display: block;
   position: fixed;
   height: // Your div height
   width: // Your div width
   top: // your window height / 2;
   left: // your window width / 2;`
}
```

The key of this problem is the position, where if you change it onto fixed, it means that element always sticks at that current position (even you scrolled).

Answer (score 0):

See [resize event documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) to get it to resize whenever the screen size is changed.

```
// grab el
const myEl = document.getElementById("yourId");
// initial styles
myEl.style.position = "absolute";
myEl.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)"; // to counter
let x,y;
// update screen positioning
function updateCoords() {
  x = window.innerWidth / 2;
  y = window.innerHeight / 2;
}
function onResize() {
  updateCoords();
  myEl.style.top = x;
  myEl.style.left = y;
}
onResize(); // start in the middle
// when window size changes, update the element position
window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
```