# Center a form for all devices: bootstrap/css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I centered my form for laptop, with this .css code:

```
form{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 20%;
}
```

And here is the result:

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fn5s.png)

But now, when I whatch it on my smartphone, I get this:

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSjTC.png)

Which is not centered.

How would you center a form for **every** devices in Bootstrap/CSS ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this class next to the row class: "justify-content-center". And delete "left: 20%" Like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

However, it won't success with absolute position. You may change that with relative position. Or check these: [How to center absolutely positioned element in div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolutely-positioned-element-in-div) or [How to center a "position: absolute" element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508275/how-to-center-a-position-absolute-element)

Answer (score 0):

Add (left and right) `margin: auto`.

```
form{
 margin: auto;
}
```

If you need top/bottom margin, set it like `margin: 5px auto`

Answer (score 0):

This will center the form using your current setup:

```
form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

But I would personally go with Atreidex's solution using existing Bootstrap classes (well, I personally wouldn't use Bootstrap, but if I already were using it, I would make use of its available classes rather than re-inventing the wheel - isn't that why you're using Bootstrap?).