# Can't responsively center div that contains divs inside

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center my div `#center` and to make it responsive to different screen sizes. I have no luck in doing that. Here's the body of my HTML page.

```
<body>
    <h1 id="panneau">Panneau de score</h1>
    <div id="center">         
      <div class="temps" id="temps">0:00</div>
      <div class="score" id="score">0</div>
      <div class="scoreDeux" id="scoreDeux">0</div>
      <h2 id="Locaux">Locaux</h2>
      <h2 id="Visiteurs">Visiteurs</h2>
    </div>
    <center><img id="EquiLogo" src="EquinoxeLogo.png" alt="Equinoxe Logo"/></center>
  </body>
```

Here's `#center`'s CSS:

```
#center { 
  width: 1100px;
  height: 1100px;       
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here's the body's CSS:

```
body {   
 max-height: 300%;
 background: linear-gradient(315deg, #808080, #a6a6a6, #ff8080, #ff4d4d);
 background-size: 3000% 3000%;
 background-position: center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Where have you got all these values from? 1100px? 300%? You could either, absolutely position it center see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508275/how-to-center-a-position-absolute-element) or you could use flexbox on a container around it.

Comment: Explain (by editing the question) how this thing is supposed to be centered, horizontally? vertically? both? what about your title and image above/below?

Comment: I first tried to solve my problem by looking up similar questions on stackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are giving a fixed `px` width to your center element, and that your body has no declared width. Add the next to your CSS

```
body {
  width:  100%; 
}

#center {
  max-width:  1100px; 
  width:  100%; 
  margin:  0 auto; 
  padding:  20px; 
  box-sizing:  border-box;
}
```

**Explanation:**

Here you will make your `body` full width.

Your `#center` element will adapt to the screen size (the `width:  100%;`) while capping at your maximum desired width (`max-width:  1100px;`).

The `margin:  0 auto;` property will center your `#center` element horizontally, while your `padding:  20px;` will provide a safe spacing between your element and the screen borders in screens smaller than 1100px (hence, will look like it is centered).

I would go a little further and even use `display:  flex;` on your `#center` element to center its content like this:

```
body {
  width:  100%; 
}

#center {
  max-width:  1100px; 
  width:  100%; 
  margin:  0 auto; 
  padding:  20px; 
  box-sizing:  border-box;
  display:  flex; 
  flex-direction:  column; 
  align-items:  center; 
  justify-content:  center; 
}
```

Comment: I tried that on a Chromebook and it's not really centered

Comment: Look at this JS fiddle. It looks pretty centered. https://jsfiddle.net/7637v5vh/2/ Is there a chance you have other styles or are not using the ones I provided? Do you need both a vertical and horizontal center or only an horizontal center?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by 'centering' `#center`, you're talking horizontally centering the text. In this case, you're looking for **[`text-align: center`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/)**. While your **[`margin: 0 auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)** is indeed the right approach for block-level elements, you need `text-align: center` for both text and inline elements.

Note that `#center` has an **enormous** fixed **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** and **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)** of `1100px`, and this won't work responsively, as it will be larger than the viewport. You'll want a percentage-based width instead, like `50%`.

If you further want to offset your image (like it was when `#center` had a large `#height`, you should instead use [**`margin-top`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-top). If you want it stuck to the bottom of the page, you should use either **[`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)** or the **[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** layout.

Both of these can be seen in the following example:

```css
#center {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  max-height: 300%;
  background: linear-gradient(315deg, #808080, #a6a6a6, #ff8080, #ff4d4d);
  background-size: 3000% 3000%;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="panneau">Panneau de score</h1>
  <div id="center">
    <div class="temps" id="temps">0:00</div>
    <div class="score" id="score">0</div>
    <div class="scoreDeux" id="scoreDeux">0</div>
    <h2 id="Locaux">Locaux</h2>
    <h2 id="Visiteurs">Visiteurs</h2>
  </div>
  <center><img id="EquiLogo" src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Equinoxe Logo" /></center>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried your method @Obsidian Age, and i tested it on a Chromebook. The #center is not really at the center of the page

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 100%` to your body tag.

Comment: How does that make any difference?