# Text not appearing after banner centered

Tags: css, html

Does anyone know how to place text after a container and it still be centered. Anyone know how to fix this? For some reason, If I don't put the position at the end if the program, it will go behind the banner picture, and if I when I try to center it doesn't work. I want them both centered, but the example to be after the banner, but whenever I try, it won't let me put the text at the right height, and be centered at the same time

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left: -10px;
}
.bottom-left {
    position: relative;
    top: 29vh;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img align="left">
    <div class="top-left">
    <img src="C:\Users\wadeb\OneDrive\Desktop\Untitled design.png" alt="Banner Picture" style="width:100vw;height:33vh" style="margin: 0px px"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-left">
    <a href="C:\Users\wadeb\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Church Website.html">Home</a>
</div>
<h3 style=" text-decoration-style: bold; position: absolute;top:34vh; text-align: center;">example:</h3>
</div>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your container has `text-align: center`. Simply add that to the text you want to add outside of the container. Or are you asking how you can have both the banner and text centered in the same line?

Comment: Just edited the main thing to be more percisce, and included the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at [How to center a "position: absolute" element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508275/how-to-center-a-position-absolute-element)
all I had to do was add

```
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
text-align: center;
```

I then simply did this

```
<span style="position: absolute; top: 38vh; left: 0%;right: 0%; text-align: center;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it all wrong, you shouldnt do img align like that simply add it after img url like this

```
<img src="url" align="left">
```

Are you asking for them both to be centered? If you are you can simply add `<center>` tag before container div and both will be centered. Be more precise.

Comment: No, The text won't appear after the image, without putting its position, which you see at the <h3> at the end

Comment: But thanks for the tip. The container/banner is not acting like its solid, it doesn't break so that text will automatically start after it

Comment: I ended up settling with making a `<span>` to make the text appear after it, by making it all positioned. Thanks anyways.