# Center an HTML element

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to center an HTML Cointainer through CSS. 
I've seen ways to center, such as the following:

```
#container{
   ...
   margin: 0 auto;
   ...
}
```

or

```
#container{
   ...
   position: relative;
   ...
}
```

but the HTML element still remains at the top left corner. 
I guess there's something wrong with the HTML code, but can't figure out what.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Roboto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(backgroung-image1.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: max-content;
}

#container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

button {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(165, 42, 42);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1> Tip Calculator</h1>
  <div id="calculator">
    <!--text box-->
    <form>
      <p>How much was your bill?</p>
      <input type="text" id="billSum" placeholder="Bill in $">
      <p>How was the service?</p>
      <select id="serviceReview">
        <option disabled selected value="0">Choose a review</option>
        <option value="0.3">Exellent</option>
        <option value="0.2">Good</option>
        <option value="0.15">Ok</option>
        <option value="0.10">Bad</option>
        <option value="0.5">Terrible</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <p>How many people share the bill?</p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Number of people" id="numberOfPeople"> people
    </p>
    <button type="button" id="calculateBtn">Calculate</button>
  </div>
  <!--tip-->
  <div id="tipSection">
    <p id="tip"> each</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Comment regarding possible duplicate**

After posting the question, another question was suggested to be answering my question.  After trying the solution in the aforementioned question, the element was centered horizontally, but not vertically. I had to add dimensions of 100px so that the element would be centered vertically as well.

Comment: Partially. I had to add dimensions to the margin property. I added 100px. There's probably a way to center it without adding dimensions, but that's good enough.

Comment: all the duplicates I added deal with horizontal and vertical centring. You have more than 100 answers and none of the below answers is bringing something new. To bad I was only restricted to 5 duplicates because I can add more

Comment: @TemaniAfif actually the op was looking for an horizontal centering without specifying any width (that was not clear in the question, not surprising for a beginner) . display:table;margin:auto; flex box or width:max-content would have been appropriate duplicate here . ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr yes already posted in many of the duplicates I added, ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10568273/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/25776315/8620333

Comment: @G-Cyr the position is also useful because we can also center using position:absolute without setting a width and I saw him commenting on some answers about vertical centring so I added one at the end for him. He also made an edit talking about vertical centring.

Comment: @TemaniAfif its vertical centering ended up with margin-top to a fixed height . this the unclear part of the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can write in your container width: 50% ; heigth: whatever you want ; and margin auto and that should fix your problem

Comment: After I changed the code as you suggested, the text is still at the left side of the screen, and now it is stretched vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
#container{
    position:absolute;
    left:30%;
    width:40%;
}
```

Set your width to whatever you want and your left will be -> `50% - width/2`

The % just scales it by window size.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use flex and forget about position not really  made for this :

basic example (run snippets in full page to see and test behavior):

```css
html {height:100vh;display:flex;}
body {margin:auto;/* instead align-items:center;justify-content:center; on HTML to avoid unwanted side effects */}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
        <h1> Tip Calculator</h1>
        <div id="calculator">
            <!--text box-->
            <form>
                <p>How much was your bill?</p>
                <input type="text" id="billSum" placeholder="Bill in $">
                <p>How was the service?</p>
                <select id="serviceReview">
                    <option disabled selected value="0">Choose a review</option>
                    <option value="0.3">Exellent</option>
                    <option value="0.2">Good</option>
                    <option value="0.15">Ok</option>
                    <option value="0.10">Bad</option>
                    <option value="0.5">Terrible</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            <p>How many people share the bill?</p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Number of people" id="numberOfPeople"> people
            </p>
            <button type="button" id="calculateBtn">Calculate</button>
        </div>
        <!--tip-->
        <div id="tipSection">
            <p id="tip"> each</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

basic example mixed with your code (position and sizing removed) Also to test in full page and resizing the window:

```css
html {height:100vh;display:flex;}
body {margin:auto;/* instead align-items:center;justify-content:center; on HTML to avoid unwanted side effects */}

/* ============  your code  ============ */
body{
    text-align: center;
    /* position: absolute; NO NEED */
    font-family: Roboto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(backgroung-image1.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
    width: max-content;
}
#container  {
/* nothing needed here for centering */
}
button{
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(165, 42, 42);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <h1> Tip Calculator</h1>
        <div id="calculator">
            <!--text box-->
            <form>
                <p>How much was your bill?</p>
                <input type="text" id="billSum" placeholder="Bill in $">
                <p>How was the service?</p>
                <select id="serviceReview">
                    <option disabled selected value="0">Choose a review</option>
                    <option value="0.3">Exellent</option>
                    <option value="0.2">Good</option>
                    <option value="0.15">Ok</option>
                    <option value="0.10">Bad</option>
                    <option value="0.5">Terrible</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            <p>How many people share the bill?</p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Number of people" id="numberOfPeople"> people
            </p>
            <button type="button" id="calculateBtn">Calculate</button>
        </div>
        <!--tip-->
        <div id="tipSection">
            <p id="tip"> each</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`margin:auto` will center a flex child in its flex parent without going hiding up or too far left(or right if `dir` is `rtl`) .

Comment: Great. Now the text is centered horizontally, yet it's still at the top of the page. How can it be centered vertically?

Comment: @random run it in full page and see it center when it's height becomes less than the window , if it is about margin, add a margin-top : xxx , but then it is not about centering but putting down a value

Comment: I added dimensions to the margin property of the body: 100px. `body{margin:100px auto}`. Now it's centered vertically. Thanks!

Comment: @random if this is your answer, you can selectit as it is and even upvote it ;) Welcome On SO

Answer (score 0):

Position `relative` itself will not center an element. You need to make sure the element you need to center is a block element for `margin: 0 auto` to work.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">This is child</div>
</div>
```

Another way is to make child element an `inline` or `inline-block` and use `text-align: center` on parent.

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.i-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child i-block">
    This is inline child
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css file:

```
body {
/* position: absolute; */
font-family: Roboto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(backgroung-image1.png);
background-size: cover;
}

/* h1 {
text-align: center;
width: max-content;
} */

#container {
margin: 100px auto;
width: auto;
height: auto;
/* position: absolute; */
padding: 70px 0;
text-align: center;
}

button {
color: white;
font-size: 15px;
background-color: rgb(165, 42, 42);
}
```

look at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Answer (score 0):

**In your case** as long as you want to use `margin: auto`, so no need to set `position` to `absolute` neither for `body` or  `#container` you only need to set `width` of `container` to any value required and `margin` will work.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

button {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(165, 42, 42);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1> Tip Calculator</h1>
  <div id="calculator">
    <!--text box-->
    <form>
      <p>How much was your bill?</p>
      <input type="text" id="billSum" placeholder="Bill in $">
      <p>How was the service?</p>
      <select id="serviceReview">
        <option disabled selected value="0">Choose a review</option>
        <option value="0.3">Exellent</option>
        <option value="0.2">Good</option>
        <option value="0.15">Ok</option>
        <option value="0.10">Bad</option>
        <option value="0.5">Terrible</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <p>How many people share the bill?</p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Number of people" id="numberOfPeople"> people
    </p>
    <button type="button" id="calculateBtn">Calculate</button>
  </div>
  <!--tip-->
  <div id="tipSection">
    <p id="tip"> each</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Centering elements can be done using multiple methods.

*refer to examples below*

#### using `margin: auto`

this will work for block elements

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}

#element {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 12%;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element">ELEMENT</div>
</div>
```

#### using `text-align: center;`

this will work for inline elements.

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#element {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element">ELEMENT</div>
</div>
```

#### using `position: absolute`

but it is not recommended to use `position: absolute` as it takes elements out of the flow and it causes mess to other elements. so use it in limited situations.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}

#element {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element">ELEMENT</div>
</div>
```

#### using `flexbox`

It is a handy and easy way to center elements both horizontally and vertically and with multiple elements included.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

#element {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element">ELEMENT</div>
</div>
```

#### using `grid`

another easy and handy method to center elements

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px;
}

#element {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element">ELEMENT</div>
</div>
```

#### Use this [Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) to learn more aboute centering.

Comment: you forgot about position:relative and/or transform:translate() with margins . ;) Personnaly i do not advise position for beginners ...

Comment: @G-Cyr those the ones I usually use. and I don't like using positioning elements. it makes a mess so I prefer simple other methods :'))

Answer (score 0):

you just do this, all the things in container will center.

**horizontally**

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

**vertical**

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't imported your css into your html script, that why the rules you wrote are not working. Import the css like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<path to css file>">
</head>
<body>
<!-- your html body -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's just how Stackoverflow snippets work, and has nothing to do with the problem.