# Is it possible with CSS to adjust the top position based on the div's height?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to show a big warning in the center of the screen when our backend sends back an error message.
Since I don't know how long that error message can be, I do not want to be restricted by setting a static size for the div, but I want it to grow if the content within it grows.

I'd like to solve this with pure css.

Ideally, I'd use something like calc, that would say: the distance from the top is 50vh minus half of the height of the div.

Currently, my css looks like this:

```
.error{
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    width:80vw;
    left:calc(10vw);
    top:calc(50vh - 100px); // should be something like calc(50vh - (.error.height / 2))
}
```

So my question is: am I thinking in the right direction? Can I request the height of a div with calc? Is there another solution?

Comment: from the duplicate**s**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25776315/8620333

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23840574/10264581. This is the best answer you'd get. :)