# CSS: Centering a content with fixed position

Tags: css, scroll, fixed, centering

I'm having trouble with keeping a layer both fixed and centered at the same time. I can't apply margin: auto as my layer doesn't have any width value, it's a fulid thing.

I found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1777282/2114455

It's a great solution to center the layer, but how do I keep this centered layer fixed (I mean, no move when scrolling)

I put them all in a position: fixed; div but this did not work. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but if you change the position of the outer div from the solution you linked to "fixed" it should work.

```
<div style="position: fixed; left: 50%;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: dotted red 1px;">
        I am some centered shrink-to-fit content! <br />
        tum te tum
    </div>
</div>
```

(fiddle of this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/TQw2j/)