# How do I horizontally center an absolute positioned element inside a 100% width div?

Tags: html, css

In the example below, `#logo` is positioned absolutely and I need it to be horizontally centered within `#header`. Normally, I would do a `margin:0 auto` for relatively positioned elements but I am stuck here. Can someone show me the way?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DeTJH/

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
    background:black;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
}

#logo {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px
}
```

Comment: Good question... what ever happened to align: center ;)... don't try that because it wont work ;)

Comment: Hey, do you realise that with CSS like that, you're positioning the logo in the window, not in the header?

Comment: @Desi margin auto works, you need to use it properly see my example

Comment: Check this also, http://stackoverflow.com/a/21446727/567854

Answer (score 298, accepted):

If you want to align center on left attribute.
The same thing is for top alignment, you could use margin-top: (width/2 of your div), the concept is the same of left attribute.
It's important to set header element to position:relative.
try this:

```
#logo {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-25px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DeTJH/2/)

If you would like to not use calculations you can do this:

```
#logo {
  background:red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/DeTJH/149/)

Comment: left: 0; right:0; did the trick for me. thanks @Alessandro

Comment: important note that's easy to forget, width must be set for this way to work

Comment: Can this be explained as well? Why does left/right:0 + margin-left/right:0 + having a defined width make this work?

Answer (score 136):

You will have to assign both `left` and `right` property `0` value for `margin: auto` to center the logo.

So in this case:

```
#logo {
  background:red;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You might also want to set `position: relative` for `#header`.

This works because, setting `left` and `right` to zero will horizontally stretch the absolutely positioned element. Now magic happens when `margin` is set to `auto`. `margin` takes up all the extra space(equally on each side) leaving the content to its specified `width`. This results in content becoming center aligned.

Comment: I like this much better than offsetting with a margin because it works with dynamic widths.

Comment: Can you explain, why this works??

Comment: Setting `left` and `right` to zero will horizontally stretch the absolutely positioned element. Now magic happens when `margin` is set to `auto`. `margin` takes up all the extra space(equally on each side) leaving the content to it's specified `width`. This results in content becoming center aligned.

Comment: @davidmdem It won't always work with dynamic widths (unless you add a child div). Consider for example a div containing text only...

Answer (score 21):

Was missing the use of `calc` in the answers, which is a cleaner solution.

```
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Works in most modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/calc

Maybe it's too soon to use it without a fallback, but I thought maybe for future visitors it would be helpful.

Comment: I think the formula in Clac function, seems to act the same as margin-left:-50px;

Comment: The diff is wrong: you have to subtract the HALF of the element's width... In this case

left: calc(50% - 25px);

Comment: You're right. Thanks! It's updated now.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, the best way is `right:0;`, `left:0;` and `margin:0 auto`. This way if the div is wide then you aren't hindered by the `left: 50%;` that will offset your div which results in adding negative margins etc.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/DeTJH/4/

```
#logo {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Yep, I said the same sometime back here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16758185/1571437 :D

Comment: thanks, i like more this method because allows you to have dynamically sizes on the item, regards!

Answer (score 4):

here is the best practiced method to center a div as position absolute

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DeTJH/5/)

code --

```
#header {
background:black;
height:90px;
width:100%;
position:relative; // you forgot this, this is very important
}

#logo {
background:red;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
width:50px;
margin: auto; // margin auto works just you need to put top left bottom right as 0
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its easy, just wrap it in a relative box like so:

```
<div class="relative">
 <div class="absolute">LOGO</div>
</div>
```

The relative box has a margin: 0 Auto;
and, important, a width...

Comment: Wow, this is great! Can't believe there are so many ways to achieve centering an absolute positioned div, but this one is definitely better then setting negative margin and works with any width as well!