# Center drop down of main menu dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have the `class="children"` centered in the middle of the page container preferably using css only but if it is not possible you can provide the best js answer.  Currently it is just a normal drop down but I want to use it as a mega menu.  If I have to add another div structure that's fine.

```
<div class="main-navigation-wrapper">
    <div class="nav pull-left">
        <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu" class="menu no-dropdown">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Blog</a>
                    <div class="children">
                        --- Children items are here
                    </div>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have seen some other examples but have attempted a few and none of them center it.  I want to find a dynamic approach to where no matter the location of the link in the menu it always centers the menu in the container.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Fiddle found here http://jsfiddle.net/YzJ4h/

Comment: Can you show what it looks like @ [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Only when you show the code and the demo using it, we will be effectively able to debug. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I horizontally center an absolute positioned element inside a 100% width div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758102/how-do-i-horizontally-center-an-absolute-positioned-element-inside-a-100-width)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest would be to add this CSS to horizontaly center your mega menu items :

*CSS :*

```
#menu li, .second-menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
#menu > li.mega_width {
    display:inline-block;
    position:static;
}
#menu > li.mega_width > .children {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:auto;
    margin:auto;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/YzJ4h/1/)**

Answer (score 4):

Do a small change in your code:

```
<div class="main-navigation-wrapper">
    <div class="nav pull-left">
        <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu" class="menu no-dropdown" style="margin: auto;">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Blog</a>
                    <div class="children">
                        --- Children items are here
                    </div>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle to debug? It will be easier!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="main-navigation-wrapper">
<div class="nav pull-left">
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu" class="menu no-dropdown" style="margin: auto;">
            <li class="menu-item four">
                <a href="#">Blog</a>
                <div class="children">
                    --- Children items are here
                </div>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough example of what you're looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/m8Vj4/

A couple main tips:

1. `position:absolute;` / `position:relative;`

   `position:absolute` will position something relative to its nearest parent that has `position:relative`.  In your case you are positioning the `.children` elements relative to their parent `li`, whereas you **want** them to be positioned relative to `.main-navigation-wrapper`
2. Centering an element with `display:inline-block;`

   You can center elements with `display:block` by adding `margin:0 auto`, however this won't work for elements with `display:inline-block`.  Instead, you can set `text-align:center` on their parent, and `text-align:left` on themselves so they don't inherit centered text.

Hope that helps... reworking your existing HTML/CSS would have taken too much time.

Comment: This won't work.  The menu is floated to the right your is not.  Yours also uses a set width, this menu could be bigger or smaller in size depending on the number of links.  I need a dynamic approach.  If this means using js that's fine.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. There is no set width, only a max-width on `.main-navigation-wrapper` (which you can remove).  The sub-menus are centered, which is what you requested. What do you mean by floated right?

Comment: The .main-navigation-wrapper has the float property applied to it.  It is floated right.  I agree I want the sub menus centered but when you float the wrapper that's what messes it up.  So that's what I am trying to work around.

Answer (score 1):

I took some liberty and added some CSS in your existing code. Those are -

```
.main-navigation-wrapper{width: 1140px; margin: 0 auto; background: #E5F0FF;}
#menu{text-align:center; padding:0px; position:relative;}

#menu li.mega-three.fullwidth{position:static;}
#menu .mega-three div.children{left:0px; box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -o-box-sizing:border-box;}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jWKy/1/).

Hope it will work for you. :-)

Comment: This only aligns it center of the .main-navigation-wrapper.

Comment: You gave the dropdown a width of 1140px. I assume your container also has same pixel width. As there were no container defined in your example, I gave `.main-navigation-wrapper` a width to show you how to do it. You can always remove the width.

Answer (score 1):

You can made certain modifications in your code. Like to avoid scrollbar in children div you have to use width:auto , and some position settings. Please do check with the code below. It may help you.

```
.menu-main-menu-container ul#menu .children {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
}

.menu-main-menu-container ul#menu .children:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}

.menu.no-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    position:static;
}
```

Modify class

```
#menu li, .second-menu li{
    position:static;
}
```

For the inner sub menus inside the children div,

```
.menu-main-menu-container ul#menu .children .children {
    position: relative;
}
```

You can please check it on fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YzJ4h/4/

Answer (score 0):

Give it Width something  like 50% to you outer div and  set margin:0 auto;

```
style="margin:0 auto;"
```

Comment: @ Anthony Russo if you give exact piece of code then someone will help becoz its not a big issue

Comment: add on parent div float this to right and use one morew inner div to width 50% and margin:0 auto; got it

Comment: i trying to solve it if got i will send you u can take the refence from here also http://www.datainfovision.com/

Comment: Use #menu-item-600 .clearfix{left: -230px;}  it will work not a good solution but you can use this

Comment: I know how to css hack it but I am looking for a dynamic approach.