# How to center variable length text in absolutely positioned element in div?

Tags: html, css

I do know the solutions from [how to center absolute positioned element in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758102/). But my situation is, instead of a fixed length div, I have a variable length text.

I want the div increase length with text while keep centered. I guess I can use js to programmatically change the width, but that sounds too hacky, is there a pure css solution?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tling/3KTUM/307/

```css
.outer_div {
  background-color: #999;
  border: 0px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.inner_div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #BBB;
  width: 100px;
  /*adjustable width with text ?*/
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_div">
  <div class="inner_div">Text Text Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting the text to always be one line?

Comment: If the text can fit with one line, then one line. If not, multiple lines is fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Center text (Horizontal and Vertical) inside a DIV block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't fully tested this on multiple browsers, but you could potentially use the `left:50%` and `transform:translate(-50%)` trick along with a `margin-right:-50%`.  It feels weird writing all of those out together, but it should cover everything.

```css
.outer_div
{
  background-color: #999; 
  border: 0px solid black; 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 200px; 
  /*float:left; */
  position: relative;
}

.inner_div
{
  position: absolute; 
  background-color: #BBB; 
  display:inline-block;
  color:black; 
  left:50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_div" style="" >
  <div class="inner_div">Text Length May Change  </div>  
</div>
<br>
<div class="outer_div" style="" >
  <div class="inner_div">Change  </div>  
</div>
<br>
<div class="outer_div" style="" >
  <div class="inner_div">Text Length May Change  Text Length May Change  </div>  
</div>
```

#### Tests:

This method works on most modern browsers at at least the latest version.  The only notable exception would be Safari 8 I think.

https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/0d780368ad54ecdd31cf5c62e70ff79f2b9a5a11

Answer (score 2):

Using a flexbox will do the trick. I took the liberty to maximize the width of the inner div equal to the outer div.

```css
.outer_div {
  background-color: #999;
  border: 0px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner_div {
  background-color: #BBB;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  /*adjustable width with text ?*/
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_div">
  <div class="inner_div">Text Text Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `text-align` attribute.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: table` and `width: auto;`

```
.inner_div {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #BBB;
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use flexbox here, as it's the easiest and most flexible option for you. 
Also, rather than using "width", you may want to consider using "max-width". This means that below a certain point, your div will resize with the text. Once it hits your set maximum, it will stop growing, and constrain the text inside the box.

[More information on flexbox.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
.outer_div {
  background-color: #999;
  border: 0px solid black;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment, use "flex-start" for top align */
}

.inner_div {
  background-color: #BBB;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 300px; /* Max-width will prevent uncontrolled growth */
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_div">
  <div class="inner_div">Variable text length.</div>
</div>
```