# Overlaying content on an image

Tags: html, css

I already have a page background so I've created `<div>` so that I can have a background image for this section and then add content over the top of it, I'm unable to get this to work, though. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
div style="position:relative; left:0; top:0;">
  <img src="BackgroundImage" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" width=100%/>
  <img src="Overlay image" style="position:relative; top:1; left:0;" width 50%/>
</div>
```

I'd like the rest of the content over that image to be centred.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused on how to use src attribute, it is meant to be a path for your images files, something like `<img src="./images/my_background.jpg"/>`

Also if you want to use an image as background, better add it into the div with CSS

```
 <div class="my_content">
   ...my content...
 </div>
 <style>
   .content{
     background-image: url(./images/my_background.jpg);
     background-position: center center;
     background-size: cover;
   }
</style>
```

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css) for multiple backgrounds in one div

Comment: I don't want it as the page background, I want it as the background for some content.

Comment: It would be the background for only the content inside my_content, you can add a background to any block element, you would add the background not the body but the element. I feel you are really confused about really basic html/css, you can check out the codecademy HTML course, will go with you step by step

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand correctly, but if you want to put a content block on top of your image, you have to create a div and then set it as `position:absolute` with some `z-index` bigger than the others.

**Update:**

I aligned with `left:25%` which is half of the 50% width, but you really should align the images with fixed units, I recommend this other stackoverflow answer to understand alignment.

[How do I horizontally center an absolute positioned element inside a 100% width div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758102/how-do-i-horizontally-center-an-absolute-positioned-element-inside-a-100-width)

```html
<div style="position:relative; left:0; top:0;width:500px">
      <div style="position:absolute; top: 0; left:0; z-index:2;">Write text here on top of all the other images</div>
      <img src="//c1.staticflickr.com/5/4533/38531735191_e41a157f7c_b.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;z-index:0; margin: 0 auto;" width=100%/>
      <img src="//c1.staticflickr.com/5/4517/24659153638_f55cc21bdc_k.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:25%;z-index:1; margin: 0 auto;" width=50%/>
</div>
```

Comment: Like that but with the top image in the center and I need to be able to overlay other content too.

Answer (score 0):

You can just have one in the background and then edit as normal, you don't need to overlay all content.