# FullScreen Images prevent Stretching

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make images full screen images ( NOT BACKGROUND ) but it is stretching on large screen size.

Is there any way to make it stays the same regardless the screen size?

I know there is a way to make background image full screen by using cover size and width/height 100% but it is possible to do it with images? Inline images?

Check it by zooming out, The picture on slider stretch.

Thank you, Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: i didn't get you. are you trying to keep the aspect ratio?

Comment: Well you're already squishing it even when not zoomed...

Comment: No, I am trying to make the image not to stretch on screen size and remain the same like: http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/css-2.php but not background!

Comment: @ Niet the Dark Absol yes but if it stays the same on zoom out then it would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep the height empty and set width to 100%. If you need a fixed height use background image but with 'cover' not 100%

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: I used your method it worked but now the text box goes to right on zoom out. any idea to make it in same area?

Comment: In exact your case use:
margin-left: -409px;
left: 50%;

For the div .orbit-caption

This is generally this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div

With a negative margin

Answer (score 0):

One way is to place your image in a div of constant size like demonstrated below:

```
<div style="height:100px; width:100px"><img src="etc/etc.png"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, But in this way the image go away from it position on zoom out

Comment: use position:fixed or position:absolute to fix it