# Absolute position within relative with margin

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to center an absolute position div within a relative dive with margin 0 auto?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer{
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.inner{
  position:absolute;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:blue;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
}
```

I was hoping that the absolute positioning would work within the outer one ok but I guess the margin. The above code can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/g4y4czff/

Ideally I'd like to use css to solve this but I reckon there's more likely to be a js solution.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

C

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center absolute element in div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g4y4czff/1/

Just add `position: relative` to `.outer`

Reason is because the default `position` property is `static`

Answer (score 0):

since you wanted it centered, here you have it centered horizontally and vertically too. Placing `position:absolute;` inside `position:relative;` allows it to be inside of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/g4y4czff/3/

```
.outer{
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}

.inner{
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:blue;
    top:0;
    margin: auto;
    left:0;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this better? Please explain. :)

Comment: because is centered vertically and horizontally too!

Comment: Throw it in your answer, bud. *Explain*. "Teach a man to fish..."