# Centering auto width content

Tags: css, center

So, I'm making these tumblr themes and I'm having trouble centering an auto width element. 
I want the info box to be in the very center of the picture (and now it's not):

http://38.media.tumblr.com/200719998b2a013bf244db059eb89559/tumblr_nars2tF6t51tko1yno1_500.png

The width of the box is not a constant, because the number (note count) could have from one to many numbers.

The current code is:

```
#info {
background-color:{color:Info Background};
color:{color:Text};
font-size:10px;
font-family:cambria;
line-height:160%;
width:120%;
height:18px;
opacity:0.8;
letter-spacing:1px;
text-align:center;
z-index:2;
}

#posts:hover .i {
opacity:1.0;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
z-index:2;
}

.i {
opacity:0.0;
width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;  /* my mistake is here somewhere, I guess*/
    top:50%;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `position: absolute` for the info box?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center absolute element in div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CSS level 3 is an option, you could use CSS transform [`translate()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#funcdef-translate) expression with negative values of `-50%` in order to center the absolute positioned element as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/u6z4tjyr/1/)**

```css
.i {
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top:  50%;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* I omitted vendor prefixes to keep
                                         This snippet short */
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    z-index:2;
}
```

This is because a percentage value for transform functions refers to the size of [bounding box](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#bounding-box).

It's worth noting that CSS transform [is supported in **IE9+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

set the element you want centered to `display: block` then its `margin-left` and `margin-right` to auto

Comment: First reasonable answer. But maybe he has a good reason for using `position: absolute`?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to center any item in a div is to use `margin:0 auto;`
It'd be easier to tell what else could be wrong if you included your html as well

Comment: You can’t do this if the ‘item’ is `position: absolute`

Comment: Good Call.  Didn't catch that

Comment: Also disagree that this is the best way to do centering. IMO the *best* way would be to set `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` on the parent element.

Comment: @Zaqx Agreed, but that really depends on the supported [browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). One can always position absolute using the whole width and then using a static/relative element with a fixed width and `margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: Wow...sounds to me like you just love being disagreeable Zaqx.  Instead of critiquing everyone else's answers why don't you just stick to being helpful by answering questions with the knowledge you have.