# Position anchor tag in the middle of masonry-brick

Tags: css, masonry

I'm trying to position an anchor tag in the middle of each of my masonry bricks but I'm having a trouble with centering it vertically since 50% of the height is not the actual height of the brick (I don't know why). The height of the anchor tag is 46px so this is my css for the anchor tags:

```
masonry-brick a
{
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    display: block;
    /* Firefox */
    margin-left: -moz-calc(50% - 23px);
    margin-top: -moz-calc(50% - 23px);
    /* WebKit */
    margin-left: -webkit-calc(50% - 23px);
    margin-top: -webkit-calc(50% - 23px);
    /* Opera */
    margin-left: -o-calc(50% - 23px);
    margin-top: -o-calc(50% - 23px);
    /* Standard */
    margin-left: calc(50% - 23px);
    margin-top: calc(50% - 23px);
    position: absolute;
}
```

but this is what it actually does: 
[image]

When I check what 100% does I see this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,
Mila

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div

Answer (score 0):

```
top: -webkit-calc(50% - 23px);
```

instead of

```
margin-top: -webkit-calc(50% - 23px);
```

Solved the issue