# Centering overlapping images in a bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overlap

I am currently trying to do something like this:

[Overlaying Image Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jSNga/)

The issue is that these are absolute positioned images so that they can overlap. I want to center these overlapping images in a Bootstrap column, like this:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
          <div id="imgdiv">
            <img id="ximage" src="css/images/x-ray-lat-left.png" width="578" height="715" border="0"/>
            <img id="emptygif" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Transparent.gif" width="578" height="715" usemap="#location-map" border="0"/> 
            <img id="overlayr1">&nbsp;</img>  
            <img id="overlayr2">&nbsp;</img>
            <img id="overlayr3">&nbsp;</img>
            <map name="location-map" id="location-map" border="0">
              <area id="r1" shape="rect" coords="250,250,340,370" href="#" alt="Hilum"/>
              <area id="r2" shape="rect" coords="90,150,340,500" href="#" alt="Heart"/>          
              <area id="r3" shape="rect" coords="130,120,460,530" href="#" alt="Righ Lung"/>
            </map>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but absolute positioning really messes things up in terms responsiveness. If I take out absolute positioning then my image gets messed up.

Any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way around this:

In all of the elements that are in the column (so in my case, the images), I included in their CSS:

```
#innerelements{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto; 
}
```

Found the answer here:

[How to center absolute element in div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to do something like this, the trick is to put the absolute positioned element inside of a relative positioned element. So wrap your images in a relatively positioned div first. Get that div acting as you want it, and then position the images inside of those.

The absolute positioned child element is relative to its parent, if that makes sense.

Comment: I added this in css to my imgdiv element:
#imgdiv{
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
}
But its centering in the middle of the browser, instead of the column.

Comment: Can you post an example somewhere?  Do you have the columns in your code inside of rows?

Comment: Sorry, yes its in rows. Just added that to my code in the question.

Comment: Ok maybe on your `#imgdiv` add `display:inline-block;` ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to control absolute positioning elements is to wrap them in a container and set the container's `position:relative;`. Then you just need to center this container to get what you want. And i believe is way easier to handle a relative position element for you.

Comment: I added this in css to my imgdiv element: #imgdiv{ position:relative; text-align: center; } But its centering in the middle of the browser, instead of the column.

Comment: Oh, i see what you mean. Try to add `margin: auto 0;` or maybe `auto`

Comment: Doesn't change... Still centering in the middle of the browser. Maybe something with the width parameter of #imgdiv?

Comment: Sorry buddy, I just came up with another option. Add `#imgdiv{ top:50%;   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%); }`    Check this link: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: Thats for a vertical align. I am looking for a horizontal align.