# Unable to align UL beneath parent p

Tags: angularjs, html, css

Here's my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0srpOqyv5o6V8NhSzhSA?p=preview

If you click on the word **Location**, the `<ul>` element is shown

I am struggling to align a `<ul>` element underneath its parent `<p>` tag.

The `<ul>` appears to always appear on the left (i know the position is absolute).

HTML:

```
 <div class="section-dropdown">
     <p>It is a
         <div class="dropdown-heading" ng-click="Location = !Location">
             Location
         </div>
         <ul ng-show="Location" class="dropdown-details">
             <li>Italy</li>
             <li>Spain</li>
             <li>Greece</li>
             <li>USA</li>
          </ul>
     </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Note that you have block level elements inside of a `<p>` tag. This is illegal and will most likely break the HTML when rendered. `.dropdown-heading` and `.dropdown-details` will most likely appear outside of the `<p>`.

Comment: @pschueller - thanks for pointing this out, how should it be corrected?

Comment: I would end the `<p>` just before the `<ul>` and change `.dropdown-heading` into a `<span>` (inline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been established, when you position the `<ul>` absolutely it is removed from the flow of the document, meaning it is positioned outside of the containing element. You can force the `<ul>` to position itself in relation to one of the parent elements by giving a parent `position: relative;`. You may then also need to add `overflow: visible;` to see any part of the `<ul>` that might overflow the parent.

Now that the `<ul>` is relative to the container you can position it accordingly, for instance:

```
.dropdown-details {
  top: 155px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

If you want the absolutely positioned `<ul>` to then be horizontally centered like the rest of the content, there is a little trick you can use (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1777282/2126792).

---

Here is your adjusted ***[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tex9QjdyDV1y04w5AoBJ?p=preview)***.

I fixed the HTML and added a wrapper around the `<ul>`:

```
<div class="section-dropdown">
  <p>It is a
    <span class="dropdown-heading" ng-click="Location = !Location">Location</span>
  </p>
  <div class="dropdown-details">
    <ul ng-show="Location">
      <li>Italy</li>
      <li>Spain</li>
      <li>Greece</li>
      <li>USA</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then positioned it in relation to the `.grid-wrap` div:

```
.grid-wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}
.dropdown-details {
  top: 155px;
  left: 50%;
}
.dropdown-details ul {
  position: relative; left: -50%;
  border: 1px dashed #ef8e80;
  padding: 9px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this has helped me understand it in detail - highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute;` It's collapsing unto itself rather than expanding the full width when you do that so it can't center the text within itself.

Comment: this was my inital fix, however when more text is below, it forces it to drop down rather than appear above: http://plnkr.co/edit/d4dMaVCmk7fAD5JpsTaa?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by drop down rather than appear above.

Comment: @So, when you click on location in the second plunker i provided, the UL appears inline... i.e the "I dont like" "Places i have been" appear below the UL... Im trying to get the UL to appear on top of them, hence the abosulute positioning

Comment: It works that way for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome - can you send me your plunker?