# CSS Positioned Absolute Element, automatic width outside of parent's bounds?

Tags: html, css, position

So, I have my parent element positioned relative, in order to allow a tooltip element to be positioned absolute inside, at the top of it. I am aware that you are required to add "left: 0, right: 0", so that the width of the element is still able to be set to auto, which I have done. However, my parent element has a fixed width, which the tooltip becomes restrained to, so the auto width cannot go outside of it, is there any way around this?

CSS:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Elements:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="tooltip">Text goes here</div>
</div>
```

No JS please, looking for a CSS solution, thanks!

Comment: Looks like your css needs `.tooltip` instead of `.child`…

Comment: @HonoreDoktorr That was just a mistake when changing the class names for here.

Comment: @isherwood This doesn't allow for the fluid width to leave the bounds of the parent element still, if my tooltip is bigger than 100px, the text will carry on outside of the element but the actual width of it will still be inside.

Comment: I was guessing. I don't really understand your scenario. Maybe a demo? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @isherwood sorry if I didn't explain enough, take a look at the example provided in Honore Doktorr's answer, it has fixed my issue, but I need the element to be displayed central, so the element should be evenly outside each left and right of the parent div.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Not setting both `left` and `right` on `.tooltip`, and setting `white-space: nowrap` should do it:

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xkok9v4p/1/).

You'd need to use **[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div)** to center an absolute element. It does require an additional element, though. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/xkok9v4p/3/)**

Comment: Thank you, this works in terms of the width, but now my element is no longer centered inside the parent unfortunately!

Comment: You can use `margin-left: -50%` for that (and not do the `margin: 0 auto`, that won’t center absolutely positioned blocks), although there are clipping issues when `.parent` is on the left side of the page. See http://jsfiddle.net/xkok9v4p/2/ for an example.

Comment: @isherwood is actually right, my second example only *seems* to work b/c of the length of my example tooltip but this one does not: http://jsfiddle.net/xkok9v4p/4/

Comment: @isherwood Put that as an answer, exactly what I needed, works perfectly thank you!

Comment: I added it to this answer.

Comment: While this does allow for "natural" sizing it also prevents the natural flow of content within the div.  The answer below allows things to display as usual but with full natural sizing and layout.

Answer (score 36):

I believe the best solution for this issue is **not setting** `left`, `right` or `white-space: nowrap` but we have a **new value** for width property `max-content`... so just add the `width: max-content;`(this one works with `max-width` as well)

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qLgw8bxu/

support: https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content

```
.tooltip {
 background-color: blue;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px 10px;

 width: max-content;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If `.parent` can be made inline, you could make `.tooltip` render as a table and it will autosize to fit its contents, but unlike with the use of `white-space:nowrap`, it would also support a `max-width`.

```
.parent {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: it is perfect, awesome like max-width

Comment: Screen readers and similar assistive technology might read this content as a table, which can bring the confusion

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this problem before, but what I think is going on, is that `width: auto;` automatically inherits the properties of its parent. So either you have to put a number in (`width: 50px;`) or a percentage (`width: 50%`).

Comment: I want the width to be fluid based on its content, at the moment it cannot go any larger than 100px of the parent, the text carries on overflowing outside of it but the actual element width is only 100px

Answer (score 1):

Use width auto with `white-space: nowrap;` and position absolute

```
.class {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```