# How do I center an absolutely positioned HTML block element? (Relative to its parent?)

Tags: html, css

I've the following HTML:

```
<div id="parent" style="height: 300px; position: relative">
  <div id="child" style="width: 100px; height: 50px; bottom: 0; position: absolute">
     ... content ...
   </div>
</div>
```

In this HTML I've positioned `#child` at the bottom of `#parent` using absolute positioning.

However I'd also like to center `#child` within `#parent`. Parent's width changes through its use case so I can't just calculate it in pixels and apply half of pixels (to center) to child's `left` property.

Applying `text-align: center` to `#parent` doesn't center `#child` as it's absolutely positioned.

Applying `text-align: center` to `#child` centers content *within* child and doesn't affects its own positioning.

Any ideas how to center `#child` within `#parent` without JavaScript, if parent sometimes dynamically changes it's width?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center absolute element in div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div)

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I'm not so sure this is duplicate because in my case I've absolute element INSIDE of relative.

Comment: @bodacydo an absolute positioned element is positioned relatively to the nearest positioned ancestor, not the viewport. So yes, it's a dupe.

Comment: Thanks everyone! All the solutions work. I accept all solutions. :)

Answer (score 2):

Position the child `left:0` and `right:0`, and set the `margin` to `auto`.

```css
#parent {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
}
#child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    ... content ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px; 
}
.child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; /* the half of the element */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is with transform:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Also, just a heads-up...your inline styles for #child & #parent are missing a ";" at the end.

Comment: Likewise for the parent, but they aren't needed there.

Comment: Indeed, edited. Did not know that, though...valid to leave off the trailing ";"?

Comment: That's correct. The same goes in your CSS rules. Since there's nothing after the last declaration it'll self-terminate.

Comment: I never thought about it self-terminating, but that makes perfect sense. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

It works with this css for the absolute positioned element:

```
#child {
 position: absolute;
 left:0; right:0;
 margin: 5px auto;
}
```

- See this tutorial: http://coursesweb.net/css/center-fixed-absolute-element_cs

Answer (score 0):

Using flextable and margin auto can center a absolute positioned element

```
        #parent{
            position:relative;
            display: flex;
        }

        #child
        {
            margin:auto; 
        }
```

Comment: Wow, what is `flex`? First time I hear.

Answer (score 0):

you could keep elements within the flux:

---

1) using the display:**table**; property (requires an extra element, here body used as so )

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
}
div {
  border:solid;
  }
body {
  display:table;
  }
#parent {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
#child {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="height: 300px; position: relative">
  <div id="child" style="width: 100px; height: 50px; ">
    ... content ...
  </div>
</div>
```

---

2) using the display:**flex**; property (young browser only).

```css
div {
  border:solid;
  }

#parent, 
#child /* want to center child content too ? */{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="height: 300px; position: relative">
  <div id="child" style="width: 100px; height: 50px; ">
    ... content ...
  </div>
</div>
```