# Center absolutely positioned div horizontally with absolute children

Tags: css, css-position

On a project I have four absolutely positioned elements on a page that sit inside an absolutely positioned container (the latter in order to align them relative to the viewport’s bottom, while more content will follow below the viewport). The four elements are next to each other and do not overlap.

Is there a way to (dynamically) center the four elements inside their absolutely positioned parent? I know it sounds weird, since absolute positioning means exactly no automatic placement. 
Dynamically would mean that responsively the elements change both size and position at a certain breakpoint, but should still be centered horizontally in the viewport at all times.

I could think of a solution like this with an additional inner div, but didn’t get my head around to actually solving the puzzle, since I don’t know a good way for the inner div to grab the total width of its four absolutely positioned child elements:

```
<div class="myAbsoluteContainer">
    <div class"myInnerDivForCentering">
        <div class="myAbsoluteChildElement" id="child1"></div>
        <div class="myAbsoluteChildElement" id="child2"></div>
        <div class="myAbsoluteChildElement" id="child3"></div>
        <div class="myAbsoluteChildElement" id="child4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the four children to be directly on top of eachother?

Comment: No, they are sitting nicely next to each other. Thanks for asking, will add it in!

Comment: Second question, do you know the heights and widths of the children?  percents or pixels?

Comment: They are in pixels and added inline by extracting the data from its WordPress image attachment that is placed inside these four child elements (each one has different sizes).

Comment: I see, so each innerDivForCentering has content on which you do not know the size of.

Comment: Well, the _myInnerDivForCentering_ div is only a guess of what could help, an additional div inside the absolutely positioned container that could possibly help centering the four child elements that are positioned absolutely ;).

Comment: Just wondering, why are the children positioned absolutely if you want them centered?

Comment: Could you please make a jsFiddle or any other snippet to work on? I'd like to have a look at the current CSS applying.

Comment: Sure, very simplified: https://jsfiddle.net/Lb2c2ykx/1/ . I left out the inner div since I only added it as a suggestion, but it is not a needed element of the website.

Comment: Centering these elements will require a positioned wrapper BUT will also mean that the elements would need to be positioned in relation to the wrapper and not the overall container / viewport. What you are asking is quite complex. Try reviewing this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div?rq=1 ) and starting over,

Comment: I am not sure why you need to absolutely position the children. Is this what you are trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/k65pxydx/. If so let me know and I will put it as an answer.

Comment: Well, you nailed it. I was so focused on the whole matter that I didn’t see I could get rid of the absolute positioning of the children. If you leave out the vertical centering (which is not needed for me) and add in margins so I have my positioning for the children (see http://jsfiddle.net/k65pxydx/2/) I have my exact answer ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you need to absolutely position the children. Is this what you are trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/k65pxydx ?

```
.myAbsoluteContainer {
    text-align: center; /* Centers the elements horizontally */
}
.myAbsoluteChildElement {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* Centers the elements vertically */
}
```

Comment: @physalis: Glad I could help. I've added the answer I gave in the comments so that you can accept it.

Comment: Thank you for taking out a complicated thinking and turning it into a simple solution for me!