# JQuery Resizable : How to make multiples divs resizing independently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I made a simple web application which allow you to add dynamic divs to a container div.

You can see how the app is looking here :

**Before resizing**

[image: application looks]

As you can see, when you click the link "Image" in the left menu, it add a new div in the div container with the black background.

Theses dynamics divs add by this way can be dragged and resized by jQuery with the jQuery ui draggable and resizable method.

the draggable function works well, but not the resizable. It seem like the divs are dependents, and when you try to resize it, it depends of the size of the others dynamics divs.

Here is the illustration of what I try to explain :

**After resize**
[image]

Like you can see, I tried to resize the div2, but because I add the div1 first, the div1 been resized too.

I want to make all div independent so I can resize it even if it overlap another div.

Here is my codes :

```js
var bg = document.getElementById('bg');
bg.className = "centrer";

var ajoutImg = document.getElementById('ajoutImage');

var initDiagonal;
var initFontSize;

ajoutImg.onclick = function () {

  var moveDiv = document.createElement("div");
  moveDiv.className = 'encadrer';
  var titre = document.createElement("p");
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  titre.textContent = "Titre";
  titre.className = 'centrerTitre';
  moveDiv.appendChild(titre);
  para.textContent = prompt("Texte de l'image :");
  para.className = 'centrerPara';
  moveDiv.appendChild(para);
  bg.appendChild(moveDiv);
  $(function () {
    $(".encadrer")
    .draggable({ containment: "parent" })
    .resizable({
      containment: "parent",
      handles: "all"
    });
  });
};
```

```css
 .centrer {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 640px;
   width: 360px;
   background-color: #000000;
 }

.menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  float: left;
}

.encadrer {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.centrerTitre {
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.centrerPara {
  font-size: 16;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

/*----- Resizable ------*/
.ui-resizable {
  position: relative;
}

.ui-resizable-handle {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.1px;
  z-index: 99999;
  display: block;
}

.ui-resizable-disabled .ui-resizable-handle, .ui-resizable-autohide .ui-resizable-handle {
  display: none;
}

.ui-resizable-n {
  cursor: n-resize;
  height: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0px;
}

.ui-resizable-s {
  cursor: s-resize;
  height: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0px;
}

.ui-resizable-e {
  cursor: e-resize;
  width: 7px;
  right: -5px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.ui-resizable-w {
  cursor: w-resize;
  width: 7px;
  left: -5px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.ui-resizable-nw {
  cursor: nw-resize;
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
}

.ui-resizable-se {
  cursor: se-resize;
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
}

.ui-resizable-ne {
  cursor: ne-resize;
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}

.ui-resizable-sw {
  cursor: sw-resize;
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
}
/*----------------------*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="menu" class="menu">
    <h3>Ajouter des éléments</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="ajoutImage" href="#" onclick="return false;">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="bg"></div>
```

I don't really know how to use the snippet system but you can see the code by this way :p

Sorry for the bad English and the var names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some `css` and `js` changes to fix your problem:

1. Replace `$(".encadrer")` to `$(moveDiv)` because you don't want to call the plugin for **all** elements (`.encadrer`) in each time the user add an image.
2. The main problem was with the `position` of the images which was `relative` I changed it to `absolut`.
3. I removed the `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`. If you want to center the image you should do this using by following [How to center absolute element in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div).

```js
var bg = document.getElementById('bg');
bg.className = "centrer";

var ajoutImg = document.getElementById('ajoutImage');

var initDiagonal;
var initFontSize;

ajoutImg.onclick = function () {
  //var moveDiv = document.createElement("div");
  //moveDiv.className = 'encadrer';
  //var titre = document.createElement("p");
  //var para = document.createElement("p");
  //titre.textContent = "Titre";
  //titre.className = 'centrerTitre';
  //moveDiv.appendChild(titre);
  //para.className = 'centrerPara';
  //moveDiv.appendChild(para);
  
  var name = prompt("Texte de l'image :");
  var container = $('<div class="encadrer"><div class="inner"><p class="centrerTitre">Titre</p><p class="centrerPara">' + name + '</p></div></div>');
  
  $(bg).append(container);
  
    container
    .draggable({ containment: "parent" })
    .resizable({
      containment: "parent",
      handles: "all"
    });
};
```

```css
.centrer {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 640px;
   width: 360px;
   background-color: #000000;
 }

.menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  float: left;
}

.encadrer {
  /*display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;*/
  border: 1px solid white;
  position:absolute !important;
}

.centrerTitre {
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.centrerPara {
  font-size: 16;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}

.encadrer:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="menu" class="menu">
    <h3>Ajouter des éléments</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="ajoutImage" href="#" onclick="return false;">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="bg"></div>
```

**Update**

To get the content center inside the `.encadrer` you need to:

1. Wrap the content with `div`
2. Follow the [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) go to: Vertically-> Is it inline or inline-* elements (like text or links)?-> Is it multiple lines? -> see the second demo. You can see the final result [here](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/ofwgD)

Comment: Thanks a lot dude you made my day ! It works perfectly thanks again !

Comment: I'm glad to here;) Good luck!

Comment: I tried to center with the margin-top and bottom : auto, but it doesn't work :/ however I have some difficulties to figure how I can center 2 <p> in one div, I'm sorry to ask you that but can you help me again please ?

Comment: Thanks i'll try ir tommorow i haven't it at my home, thanks you very much :)

Comment: Hi dude, I'm sorry to ask for your help again, but I'm trying to add 2 functions at this code :
The first one I tried was to put the title "Titre" at the top of the container, but I can't do that, when I try to change just one thing of your code, all is broken :( I tried to put a new global div with the title on the top then I added the container, but that don't work... I don't really understand how all the code are working

Comment: Sorry, I can't help until sunday. Maybe you can ask here a new question and I'm sure that people will be happy to help you. You can add a comment here with the link to the new question and in sunday I will be happy to help you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks again for your attention, it can wait sunday no problems !
I posted my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358381/css-issue-jquery
Anyway thanks for your help !