# How to fix vertical alignment of title and content inside resizable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When we hit the 'add image' button to the left, it adds a div with 2 `<p>` draggable and resizable into a container.
There is one `<p>` which is a Title (Titre) and another `<p>` which is the content of the div.

Here is the code :

```css
.centrer {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
 height : 768px;
 width : 432px;
 background-color : #000000;
}

.menu {
 border:1px solid black;
 padding-left:15px;
 padding-right:15px;
 padding-top:2px;
 padding-bottom:2px;
 float:left;
 text-align : center;
}

h3, li, ul{
 text-align : left;
}
 
.encadrer {
 border: 1px solid white;
 position:absolute !important;
}
 
.centrerTitre{
 color : white;
 margin : auto;
 text-align : center;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;
}
 
.centrerPara{
 font-size: 16;
 color : white;
 margin : auto;
 text-align : center;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;
}

.inner {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
}

.encadrer:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

/*----- Resizable ------*/
.ui-resizable { position: relative;}
.ui-resizable-handle { position: absolute;font-size: 0.1px;z-index: 99999; display: block;}
.ui-resizable-disabled .ui-resizable-handle, .ui-resizable-autohide .ui-resizable-handle { display: none; }
.ui-resizable-n { cursor: n-resize; height: 7px; width: 100%; top: -5px; left: 0px; }
.ui-resizable-s { cursor: s-resize; height: 7px; width: 100%; bottom: -5px; left: 0px; }
.ui-resizable-e { cursor: e-resize; width: 7px; right: -5px; top: 0px; height: 100%; }
.ui-resizable-w { cursor: w-resize; width: 7px; left: -5px; top: 0px; height: 100%; }
.ui-resizable-nw { cursor: nw-resize; height: 7px; width: 7px; top: -5px; left: -5px; }
.ui-resizable-se { cursor: se-resize; height: 7px; width: 7px; right: -5px; bottom: -5px; }
.ui-resizable-ne { cursor: ne-resize; height: 7px; width: 7px; top: -5px; right: -5px; }
.ui-resizable-sw { cursor: sw-resize; height: 7px; width: 7px; left: -5px; bottom: -5px; }
/*----------------------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Affichage</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  
 
 <body>
  <div id="menu" class="menu">
   <h3>Taille de l'écran</h3>
   
   <select id='selector'>
    <option value="1920x1080">1920x1080</option>
   </select>
   </br></br>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="radio" id="portrait" name="orientation" value="portrait" checked="checked">Portrait</td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="paysage" name="orientation" value="paysage">Paysage</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </br>
   <h3>Ajouter des éléments</h3>
   <ul>
    <li><a id="ajoutImage" href="#" onclick="return false;">Image</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="bg"></div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var bg = document.getElementById('bg');
   bg.className = "centrer";
   
   var ajoutImg = document.getElementById('ajoutImage');
   
   var initDiagonal;
   var initFontSize;

   var rad = document.getElementsByName('orientation');
   
   for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].onclick = tailleEcran;
   }
   
   document.getElementById("selector").addEventListener("change", tailleEcran, false);
   
   ajoutImg.onclick = function() {
   
    //var name = prompt("Texte de l'image :");
    
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.className = 'encadrer';
    var inner = document.createElement("div");
    inner.className = 'inner';
    var titre = document.createElement("p");
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    titre.textContent = "Titre";
    titre.className = 'centrerTitre';
    inner.appendChild(titre);
    para.textContent = prompt("Texte de l'image :");;
    para.className = 'centrerPara';
    inner.appendChild(para);
    container.appendChild(inner);
    
    //var container = $('<div class="encadrer"><div class="inner"><p class="centrerTitre">Titre</p><p class="centrerPara">' + name + '</p></div></div>');
    bg.appendChild(container);
     
    $(container)
    .draggable({containment:"parent"})
    .resizable({
     containment:"parent",
     handles: "all"
    });
   };
   
   function tailleEcran() {
    switch(document.getElementById("selector").value){
     case '1920x1080' :
      if(document.getElementById("portrait").checked == true){
       bg.style.height = '768px';
       bg.style.width = '432px';
      }else{
       bg.style.height = '432px';
       bg.style.width = '768px';
      }
     break;
    }
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can see that the 'Titre' stays at the middle of the page when you resize. I **want this title to stay at the top of the div (the white square) but the content to stay at the middle.** This is very noticeable after you resize the white squares.

Comment: Please simplify your question to ask about just *one* issue, and clarify it as well as you can. Edit your title to pose a proper question.

Comment: Bunch of code is inconvenience to see

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve with this title. When I test your code, the box with white border is draggable, and starts at the top left of your black box. the text in this box is centered. Can you rephrase maybe?

Comment: When you resize the white square, both title and content stay at the middle. He wants it to keep the title at the top and content in the middle when resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has i understand you just need to stick the title on the top of your square.
You can do it by adding this to the centerTitre class:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Tell me if that's you want.

Comment: Thanks it is what i was looking for ! I'll post my second question in another post, thanks a lot ! :)