# Center absolute div in another div

Tags: html, css

is there a way to place a absolute div inside his parent centered and above the content with z-index?

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="absolute-centred"></div>
</div>
```

The size of the parent is unknown. the absolute div should be overlaying the content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center absolute element in div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easy way to vertically and horizontally center a div into another goes like this:

```css
.container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100px; /* not part of solution */
 height: 100px; /* not part of solution */
 background-color: #808; /* not part of solution */
 border-radius: 50%; /* not part of solution */
}
.content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center; /* not part of solution */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">I'm absolutly centered</div>
</div>
```

You could also nest your horizontal/vertical alignment to another `absolute` positioned div. Your parent `relative` could be an `absolute`, or `fixed` if you prefer.

If you just want vertical align, use `translateY(-50%)` and if you want horizontal align, use `translateX(-50%)` with complementary `top` or `left` property.

And last, you could change 50% to whatever you want to not only « center » content.

Comment: I was a tiny bit faster but I removed my answer since yours has the fiddle.

Comment: awesome! Thank you very much.