# How to center 2 absolute divs

Tags: html, css, alignment

I know that I can center an absolute div in front of every other element like this.

**HTML**

```
<div class='otherDiv1'></div>
<div class='otherDiv2'></div>
<div class='otherDiv3'></div>
<div class='otherDiv4'></div>

<div class='centerDiv'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.centerDiv{
    position:absolute;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-indez:100; // Just a test number, just to ensure this div is in front of every other element
}
```

So in that way the div would be perfectely align to the center and responsive.

[image]

**So my question is the following:**

What is the best way to place 2 divs perfectly align like the previous one like and also be responsive

**IN BIG SCREENS**

[image]

**IN SMALL SCREENS**

[image]

If you have any idea how to do that please let me know (:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center absolute element in div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div)

Answer (score 1):

Store the 2 divs inside 1 absolute positioned div that is centered.

Comment: It's not exactly a complex solution.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.centerDiv {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 80%;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }
    
    .centerDiv2 {
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 45%;
    }
    
    .left,.right {
 
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
        .left,
        .right {
            display: block;
        }
        .left {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>stack</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 
</head>

<body>

        <div class='centerDiv'>
            <div class='centerDiv2 left'>abc</div>
            <div class='centerDiv2 right'>xyz</div>
        </div>


</body>

</html>
```

i think you need this type of design.if not please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Set a center div with position and add two div incide it. Refer the below html

**HTML**

```
<div class='otherDiv1'></div>
<div class='otherDiv2'></div>
<div class='otherDiv3'></div>
<div class='otherDiv4'></div>

<div class='centerDiv'>
  <div class='centerDiv1'>
  </div>
  <div class='centerDiv2'>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code::

HTML:

```
<div class='otherDiv1'>abc</div>
<div class='otherDiv2'>abc</div>
<div class='otherDiv3'>abc</div>
<div class='otherDiv4'>abc</div>

<div class='centerDiv'>
  <div class='centerDiv2 left'>xyz</div>
  <div class='centerDiv2 right'>yzrr</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centerDiv{
display: inline-block;
width: 80%;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
}

.centerDiv2{
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 40%;
}

.left{
float: left;
}

.right{
float: right;
}
```