# How can I center this datepicker in my form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yxhI.jpg
this is what it looks like at the moment. Id like it to be in the center of the screen if possible. here is the code for the datepicker part

```
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-left: 20px;">
     <div id="datepicker-container">
      <div id="datepicker-center">
       <input type="text" id="from" class="form-control" style="width: 180px"/>
       <input type="text" id="to" class="form-control" style="width: 180px"/>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

and the JS

```
$(function () {
$("#from").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$("#to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
});
```

I was trying this CSS, but it doesnt work

```
 #datepicker-container{
text-align:center !important;
}
#datepicker-center{
display:inline-block !important;
margin:0 auto !important;
}
```

Cant get fiddle to run the datepicker. heres a link too the site. http://bbennett36.github.io/firstclass/bookatrip.html

Comment: Could you please provide us a fiddle?

Comment: If you have a static width on the parent container of the datepicker, you can set a margin: 0 auto; on the parent to center it. Let me know if you don't have a set width on the parent.

Comment: ya please provide in fiddle. because when we put this on fiddle then only two textboxes shows

Comment: fiddle doesnt seem too like the datepicker. heres a link too the site. http://bbennett36.github.io/firstclass/bookatrip.html

Comment: Repeat question. Your datepicker is positioned absolute. Have a look at this answer...http://stackoverflow.com/a/1777282/1379450

Comment: Hmm, im not sure how to call that on the actual datepicker prompt. That answer only affects the input boxes.

Comment: regardless of correct solution, avoid using `!important`

Comment: yeah that was just an answer i saw to a similar question, figured I would give it a try. They said the JS will override the CSS sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try overriding inline css with

```
.ui-datepicker{ left: 50% !important; margin-left: -25.5em !important;}
```

25.5em is the half of width of calendar container

Comment: I got it too center with  .ui-datepicker{margin-left: -10em;}, ill have to try it on different screens.

Comment: It won't work, datepicker always set style.left on popup

Comment: Your new edit seems to be working. Let me test a couple more things.                     Yes this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have fixed style `left: 577.172px` in your html:

```html
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker 
ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all 
ui-datepicker-multi ui-datepicker-multi-3" style="position: absolute;
top: 459px; left: 577.172px; display: block; z-index: 4; width: 51em;">
```

- remove the left attribute from <html>
- add

  `#ui-datepicker-div{left: 50%; margin-left: -25.5em;}`
  *- either in css or html (as initially used)
   - use id's for css precedence
   - no need for !important*