# Center an abolute poseitioned element inside its parent element

Tags: html, css

I want to center a div element that have a position value of absolute inside of its parent element. I want so center it both vertically  and horizontal.

How would i do that?

```html
<div class="parent_div">
  <div class="centered_div">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <a href=""><img src="img" alt="image"></a>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
 </div>
```

So the centered_div should be centered in the parent_div

Comment: can you provide your code here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: Include the code so that it may be used as a reference to demonstrate a working solution and indicate what you have already tried.

Comment: This question has been asked a million times already. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically).

Comment: Bryan then the element is centered in the  middle of the webpage  og want to center it in the middle og the parent element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center absolutely positioned element in div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolutely-positioned-element-in-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting the parent's position to relative. Then set the child's top, right, bottom, and left properties to 0, and setting the margin to auto.

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

### Edit

As mentioned, using top, right, bottom, and left properties set to 0 with auto margins **only works if the child element has a set width and height**. Otherwise, the child will simply fill the entire width and height of the parent. If you want to center a child **without** specifically setting it's width and height, you can do it using the CSS [translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) function.

First you can center the top left corner of the child by setting the child's top and left to 50% of it's parent's width and height. Then shift it over and up by 50% of it's own width and height.

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For this method to work the nested *absolutely positioned* element would require explicitly defined `height` and `width` property values. Consider including a solution for cases which do not have explicitly defined property values of this type.