# Centering a position absolute element using translateX(-50%) doesn't center div

Tags: html, css

I have div a `container` with two elements inside, `el` and an absolute positioned element `pp`. `el` shares the same width and height as the `container` and their width **can be dynamically changed**.

`pp` should be centered to `el` and the `container`. I have a red marker in the middle of the `pp` div to mark it's center.

With a 30px width to the `container` and `el`, to center `pp` I used, `translateX(-50%)`. From my understanding this should center `pp` to `el`. But actual result is not that. -50% moves the div a little further to the left. When tweaking -43% centers the red marker.  But this -43% is not applicable to  another `el` div with a different width.

How do I always center the `pp` container using `translateX` to another div of any size.

```css
.container {
     width: 30px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
 .el {
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     background-color: pink;
     border-radius: 100%;
}
 .pp {
     position: absolute;
     max-width: 300px;
     background-color: yellow;
}
 .pp1 {
     transform: translateX(-50%);
}
 .pp2 {
     transform: translateX(-43%);
}
```

```html
Not centered when translateX is -50%
<br />
<br />
<div class="container">
   <div class="el">
      elem
   </div>
   <div class="pp pp1">
      <div style="width:10px; height: 10px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: red;"></div>
      popoverasdasd asjdjasd sdfsdfsdfsdf
   </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
Expected result comes when translateX is -43%
<br />
<br />
<div class="container">
   <div class="el">
      elem
   </div>
   <div class="pp pp2">
      <div style="width:10px; height: 10px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: red;"></div>
      popoverasdasd asjdjasd sdfsdfsdfsdf
   </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v6o5z8a0/

Comment: You are required to post your markup here within your question, not a jsfiddle. Links go dead and will help no one in the future. [mcve]

Comment: You need `left: 50%` in addition to `translateX(-50%)`. The left style positions the left edge of the content in the exact centre, the translate rule then moves the content so the exact centre of it is where the left edge was (which should be the centre of your container).

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: @delinear is correct. that should be the answer.

Comment: I posted it as a comment as I expected this to get closed as an obvious dupe, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolutely-positioned-element-in-div?rq=1 (and the reason I didn't just link to the dupe is because the top two answers on there are pretty outdated, but the solution I offered is answer number 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I changed the code a little to see what it was doing.

The comments are correct, you must do a `left: 50%` and a `transform: translateX(-50%);`.

The `left:50%` will move the left side of your inner element to the middle of the parent element. And the `transform: translateX(-50%);` will move the inner element back by 50% of its width. This will center the object in the parent.

Part of the problem in your example was:

- The lack of a `position: relative` on the parent container.
- Setting the parent container to 30px. For this to work well the parent should take 100% width.
- Forgetting the `left: 50%` in the `.el` and `.pp` rules.

```css
.container {
  height: 80px;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
  position: relative;
}

.el {
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 30px;
}

.pp {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pp1 {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.pp2 {
  transform: translateX(-43%);
}
```

```html
Not centered when translateX is -50%
<br />
<br />
<div class="container">
   <div class="el">
      elem
   </div>
   <div class="pp pp1">
      <div style="width:10px; height: 10px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: red;"></div>
      popoverasdasd asjdjasd sdfsdfsdfsdf
   </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
Expected result comes when translateX is -43%
<br />
<br />
<div class="container">
   <div class="el">
      elem
   </div>
   <div class="pp pp2">
      <div style="width:10px; height: 10px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: red;"></div>
      popoverasdasd asjdjasd sdfsdfsdfsdf
   </div>
</div>
```