# How do i align footer and header at with minimal height when printing a page using html and css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is, creating a layout like `Magzine`. I use `CSS Grid` in my `HTML` to create a layout, anyhow layout looks good when i render it or open it in a browser, but when i hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to take a print out the `Header` and `Footer` are getting distorted, what i want is like they will appear in the middle with some padding on both `Header` and `Footer`

[image]

As you can see the footer going into left and the `body` text and `header` are getting collapsed with each other. Same is happening with footer.

[image]

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
    padding: 1cm;
    margin: 1cm auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
}

header,
footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
h1{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(12, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto-fill, auto);
    grid-template-areas: "h h h h h h h h h h h h" "m m m c c c c c c c c c" "l l l l l l r r r r r r";
}

.container>div {
    column-count: 2;
}

p::first-letter {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    column-span: all;
}

.container>.item_LayoutOne_100Percent {
    grid-area: h;
}

.container>.item_LayoutTwo_50Percent_layoutOne {
    grid-area: l;
}

.container>.item_LayoutTwo_50Percent_layoutTwo {
    grid-area: r;
}

.container>.item_LayoutThree_75Percent {
    grid-column: c;
}

.container>.item_LayoutFour_25Percent {
    grid-column: m;
}
h1{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 11mm 17mm 17mm 17mm;
}

@media print {
    footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        margin:-10px;
    }
    header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
    p {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    html,
    body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Magzine Design</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- <script src="main.js"></script>  -->
    
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Some Content Name</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-block item_LayoutOne_100Percent">
            <h2>Demo Heading for 100% Layout</h2>
            It was this, as much as anything, that gave people courage, and I suppose the new arrivals from Woking also helped
                to restore confidence. At any rate, as the dusk came on a slow, intermittent movement upon the sand pits
        </div>
        <div class="content-block item_LayoutTwo_50Percent_layoutOne">
            <h2>Demo Heading for 50% Layout</h2>
            it was this, as much as anything, that gave people courage, and I suppose the new arrivals from Woking also helped
                to restore confidence. At any rate, as the dusk came on a slow, intermittent movement upon the sand pits
        </div>
        <div class="content-block item_LayoutTwo_50Percent_layoutTwo">
            <h2>Demo Heading for 50% Layout</h2>
                it was this, as much as anything, that gave people courage, and I suppose the new arrivals from Woking also helped to restore
                confidence. At any rate, as the dusk came on a slow, intermittent movement upon the sand pits began
        </div>
        <div class="content-block item_LayoutFour_25Percent">
            <h2>Demo Heading for 25% Layout</h2>
                it was this, as much as anything, that gave people courage, and I suppose the new arrivals from Woking also helped to restore
                confidence. At any rate, as the dusk came on a slow, intermittent movement upon the sand pits began
        </div>
        <div class="content-block item_LayoutThree_75Percent">
            <h2>Demo Heading for 75% Layout</h2>
                it was this, as much as anything, that gave people courage, and I suppose the new arrivals from Woking also helped to restore
                confidence. At any rate, as the dusk came on a slow, intermittent movement upon the sand pits began
        </div>

    </div>
    <footer>
        Some Content Name
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my snippet, please help me if I am doing wrong somewhere, I have tried many methods on `@print` like providing `padding` or `margin` to the header and footer, but nothing worked.

Comment: Please only provide minimal code required to represent your issue. We don't need walls of boiler plate text to have to scroll through to review your html structure. See [mcve]

Comment: Your question title and question text seem to be asking different questions. The title is about numbering footers; the text seems to be about distorted/collapsed content. What's your actual question? Please keep the guidelines from [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) in mind, such as keeping your question specific, targeted, and concise.

Comment: Sorry for the `Title and Question text`, i have edited my question.

Comment: It still does seem to ask two questions. I also don't think that the code in your question produces the problem you describe. It does look fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated solution in @media print {}

```css
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    margin:-10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I've used this code several times in my projects, which is inspired by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8273750/9983227). Specifying both `left` and `right` as `0` allows a `margin` of `auto` to center the elements within the `<body>`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply but if i remove position fixed from both `header` and `footer`, then it will not appear on every page when i used to print the pages.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested my updated code to make sure it works with multiple pages, and it does. The header and footer are centered at the bottom and top on each page.