# Centering child that has position absolute to a parent with display flex

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position, centering

How can I center/middle a child element with position absolute. On a parent that has display flex?

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Object
  </div>
</div>

.parent{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.child{
  position: absolute;
}
```

The child element has to overlap the parent.

Comment: position:relative to parent and a classic centring

Comment: Set parent element as relative, after this, you can center his child as always. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolutely-positioned-element-in-div

Comment: add `justify-content: center;` to the parent

Comment: When I do that it's stll not in the middle.

Comment: It works now thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```css
.parent{
display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   position: absolute;
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.child{
  position: absolute;
  background-color:#f00;
  border:1px solid #333;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Object
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works now I had to add transform: translate(0, -50%); to get it in the middle.