# how to center text with the calc() function in css

Tags: html, css

I'm making a fancy page that need to have some text centered, i can't use the `text-align: center;` thing because i have a `position: absolute;`. So now i need the be able to center the text horizontaly with the calc() function instead (also because i want to do some other fancy stuff with it).

This is what i tried and didn't work:
CSS:

```
#center {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:calc(100vw /2 - attr(length) /2);
}
```

HTML:

```
[...]

<div id="center">test</div>

[...]
```

As shown above I've tried using attr(), but I don't know which value to put inside to obtain what i want (and infact firefox refuse to make it work)

In the answer please consider that text will change on the fly.
The text shoud be always centered.

hope you understood and can help

Comment: That'll center the whole element, not just the text. Sounds like an XY problem?

Comment: why would the DIV's position effect the text alignment?

Comment: @BenM what does "XY problem" mean?

Comment: @Doug https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: you are simply complicating an easy task .. duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/1776915/8620333

Comment: alrigth what else do you suggest?

Comment: check the link I shared

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's not complety cenering the text, because if the text is very long you will notice that the text will no longer lloks centered

Comment: @EnryFrafranci you already checked all the 41 answers?

Comment: well i was thinking you refered to the first one . . . still showrin did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this. Hope it will be helpful to you.

```css
#center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="center">test</div>
```

Comment: thank you, what i wanted

Comment: Welcome @EnryFrafranci . By the way if this works for you please mark the answer as accepted. :)