# horizontal center align an div with flexible with

Tags: css

I need horizontal center align an flexible width `div` element.

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"> ...this content will grow or shrink while on items changed... </div>
</div>
```

```css
.outer {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

As you can see the `div.inner` is perfectly horizontal center aligned, but its max width will always be 50% of the `div.outer` while I hope the max width could be more when the content is grown.

And:

- I don't want to give `div.inner` a fixed or min with, I hope it's flexible;
- I know "max-width" does not work

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8273750/8620333

Comment: I need a flexible width box while the post you give is fixed width `div`. Gerard show me a flex layout and it solve my problem. Thanks any way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
.outer {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"> ...this content will grow or shrink while on items changed... </div>
</div>
```