# How do I position an image at the bottom center inside a div?

Tags: html, css, image, position, css-position

Im trying to position an image in center and bottom of a div, now I have this:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JModF.png)

and I need to do this: [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC2Vw.png)

I need to center the cellphone image in the div, my code:

```
    .titulo {
      position: relative;
    }
    .titulo img {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
<section class="titulo">
    <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <img src="/img/background/whatsapp.png" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Here is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-can-i-center-an-absolutely-positioned-element-in-a-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**short answer:**
Try adding these 2 lines of `CSS` to your `<img>` child

```css
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

**explanation:**

[image]

using `left` the image moves to the center
but the center point will match the left side,

so using `translate` we divide the image in half
and it is moved so that it is perfectly centered!

**code example:**

```css
.phone {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* the solution */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.bg {
  /* change this link to yout background image (not the phone) */
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy91H.jpg");
  /* this make the background -> responsive */
  background-size: cover;
  /* take 100% of the space */
  /* (if you need less than 100% don't change this, instead change the parent height) */
  height: 100%;
  /* this line is important, and is needed for making the position work in image or childrens */
  position: relative;
}

* {
  /* this solve the scroll problem */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  /* this solve the little margin on body tag (chrome) */
  margin: 0;
  /* html take the 100% of height */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!--background-->
<section class="bg">
  <!-- phone -->
  <img class="phone" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfq59.png" />
</section>
```

**results:**
[image]