# How to position ::before element in the middle top of flex-item?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-position

I have cards with team members, where is name, position and some description. The cards are flex items.
I put profile picture as a ::before element and positioned it in the middle top of the flex item so it looks like this:
[image]

The problem is - between breakpoints 430 and 790px, it is not in the middle - it looks like this:
[image]

My code is:

```css
.card-team-member {
  --profile-img-height: calc(var(--breakpoint_unit) * calc(80*var(--basic_unit)));
  flex-basis: calc(var(--breakpoint_unit) * calc(190*var(--basic_unit)));
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: calc(var(--breakpoint_unit) * calc(10*var(--basic_unit))) calc(var(--breakpoint_unit) * calc(15*var(--basic_unit)));
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--profile-img-height) - 1%);
  position: relative;
}

.card-team-member::before {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% - calc(var(--breakpoint_unit) * calc(125*var(--basic_unit))));
  top: calc(var(--breakpoint_unit) * calc(-55*var(--basic_unit)));
  width: calc(var(--breakpoint_unit) * calc(80*var(--basic_unit)));
  height: var(--profile-img-height);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

 :root {
  --basic_unit: 0.5vw;
  --breakpoint_unit: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 430px) {
   :root {
    --breakpoint_unit: 0.8;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 570px) {
   :root {
    --breakpoint_unit: 0.6;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 790px) {
   :root {
    --breakpoint_unit: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="section-about-us-team">
  <div class="section-container about-us">

    <div class="div-team-member">
      <div class="card-team-member one">
        <h5>Name Surname</h5>
        <h6>CEO</h6>
        <p>text</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card-team-member two">
        <h5>Name Surname</h5>
        <h6>IT</h6>
        <p>text</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card-team-member three">
        <h5>Name Surname</h5>
        <h6>IT</h6>
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Do you have any ideas why is it not working?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You're trying way too hard. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23384995/1264804. `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)`