# Absolute Positioning & Text Alignment

Tags: html, css

I would like some text to be centered in the bottom of the screen.

I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HRz6X/), but it doesn't work. It looks like absolute positioning conflicts with the alignment.

How could I achieve this simple task ?

Comment: the last answer accepted, which is simply repeated other solutions. Lol.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center Align on a Absolutely Positioned Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252856/center-align-on-a-absolutely-positioned-div)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

The div doesn't take up all the available horizontal space when absolutely positioned.  Explicitly setting the width to 100% will solve the problem:

**HTML**

```
<div id="my-div">I want to be centered</div>​
```

**CSS**

```css
#my-div {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 15px;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
}
```

​

Comment: That is ridiculously simple ... but.... I found this post by looking for the answer to this question.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Edward, without left:0; there appeared a horizontal scroll bar!

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HRz6X/2/

You need to add `left: 0` and `right: 0` (not supported by IE6). Or specify a width

Comment: Works in IE8 and IE7. If you're using IE6, you need to upgrade.

Comment: Are you sure about IE7?) IE6/7 implied

Comment: You should always state a good reason to do it. Answer must why need to use `left:0` and `right:0`

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```css
#my-div { 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe specifying a width would work. When you `position:absolute` an element, it's width will shrink to the contents I believe.

Answer (score 1):

just add left:0; right:0;  or add width

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: 500;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
text-align: center;
```

Comment: Please explain your post, which looks like a dump of some CSS