# DIV changed its behaviour when "position:absolute" was added to it. Why?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm new to CSS and I have a question.

First, my HTML and CSS code:

```
<!-- HTML CODE -->

<body>

    <div id="container">Container



    </div>
     <div id="inner">Inner</div>

</body>

<!-- CSS CODE -->


 #container { 
        background-color:#b6ff00;
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        position:relative;
        }

        #inner {
        background-color:#ffd800;

        }
```

With current code, the browser shows the following page:

[image]

This is expected.

But if I add this css property to #inner element `position:absolute;` there will be a following output:

[image]

As you can see, the #inner div, takes only that much space it needs. Why this changed with only `position:absolute;` property added to #inner div?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute Positioning & Text Alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808592/absolute-positioning-text-alignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when you use `position: absolute;` the element will take up `width` upto the elements defined/content it contains., cuz it just gets out of the document flow so it is block level in nature but won't take up entire horizontal space on the document, as it's just out of the flow of the document..

If you want it to be full `width` you need to define `width: 100%;` explicitly so that it will take 100% of the relative parent's `width` as well as the `height` if you declare `height: 100%;`

Also, make sure you always use `position: absolute;` with a wrapper element set to `position: relative;` or your element will fly out in the wild which will eventually end up taking the viewport as the last relative wrapper if you set the position of the element using `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left`.

I've explained here in detail, that how [CSS Positioning Works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718577/how-css-positions-work-why-absolute-elements-stack-up-on-each-other-instead-of)

---

Worth to note that, you make any element a `position: absolute;` element, it will behave as a block level element, but you need to define `height` and `width` so for example, if you turn an *inline* `span` element a `position: absolute;` you can define `height` and `width` without making it `display: block;` *(Unless and until you are using `display: none;` initially)*

Answer (score 2):

`position: absolute;` does not behave the same as `block` elements.

You will need to set a width and a height for a div that is absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamentally how position absolute works. Once taken out of the flow of the document it becomes an inline-block element that is absolutely positioned within the nearest element that is positioned relatively (or the top most element)

If you need it to then be a certain dimensions you can try to set widths and heights, or you can do things like

```
#inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
}
```

...which would ensure it always stuck to the left and right sides of the screen.

It's generally good practice to put things that are positioned absolutely inside of an element with "position:relative" on it, as your code stands it suggests you want your #inner element to be placed anywhere on the page, whereas if you wanted it to be of a size and position relative to #container your code should look like this:

```
<body>

    <div id="container">
        Container
        <div id="inner">Inner</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

with CSS such as:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  #inner {
    background-color:#ffd800; width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    }
```

You can see your output here:-
       http://jsfiddle.net/KggJd/

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain a little:

**Postition: relative**

This will align itself in accordance with the elements found before (i.e) Prior Siblings.
You can change the position by using margin-top, margin-left, ....

**Position: absolute**

This will always consider from the browser's start point and won't be in accordance with anything.

Drawbacks:

You cannot consider this as the parent or anything when absolutely positioned.

You can change its position by using top, bottom, right, left.