# Element not coming to center. I am using absolute?

Tags: html, css

div #introbox is not centering. I have used container as relative and introbox as absolute. I have set top,bottom,left and right as 0. Still box is not centring. I want to centre the introbox in the intropic.

```css
html,body{
     padding: 0;
     margin:0;
    }
    
    
    .container{
     width: 960px;
     margin:0 auto;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    #header{
     width: 100%;
     height: 120px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    
    #nav{
     height: 55px;
     border-bottom: 4px solid lightblue ;
    }
    
    #intro-pic{
     height: calc(100vh - 181px);
     width: 100%;
     background: url("img/introbg.jpg") center fixed;
    }
    
    #intro-box{
     height: 55vh;
     width: 800px;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.74);
     border-radius: 15px;
     position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      left:0px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="header">
     <div class="container">
      Header
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="nav">
     <div class="container">
      Nav
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="intro-pic">
     <div class="container">
      <div id="intro-box">
       sdfdsfds
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems to be working in the code snippet I made for your code when on full screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center Align on a Absolutely Positioned Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252856/center-align-on-a-absolutely-positioned-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `transform:translate` will work for any size div.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
}
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height:100vh;
}
#intro-box {
  height: 55vh;
  width: 800px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74);
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  /* vertical centering */
}
```

```html
<div id="intro-pic">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="intro-box">
      sdfdsfds
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it to be vertically centered!

Comment: Updated to center vertically

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code.

Make left position 50% and give margin-left half of the wrapper width value.

```
#intro-box{
    height: 55vh;
    width: 800px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.74);
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -400px; /* Half of the wrapper width */
}
```

Try below example if you are trying exact center (from top & left)

```
#intro-box{
    height: 55vh;
    width: 800px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.74);
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -400px; /* Half of the wrapper width */
    margin-top: -27.5vh; /* Half of the wrapper height*/
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/edbstv23/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#intro-box {
    height: 55vh;
    width: 800px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.74);
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -400px;
    margin-top: -27.5vh;
}
```

But again, `.container` should have height over or equal to `#intro-box`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to center Elements:

1. using line-height:

you want to center text and you know the size of the box:

```css
.box { background: red; height: 200px; }
.box span { display:block; text-align: center; line-height: 200px; }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

2. using transform:

you want to center anything but dont know the size of your box:

```css
.box, .box2 { background: red; height: 200px; }
.box span { top: 50%; text-align: center; position: relative; display: block; transform: translateY(-50%) }
.box2 span { top: 50%; left: 50%; position: relative; display: inline-block; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>Text</span>
</div>

OR WITHOUT TEXT-ALIGN:
<div class="box2">
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

3. using absolute position:

you know the height of the element you want to center

```css
.box, .box2 { background: red; height: 200px; position: relative; width: 100%; }
.box span { position: absolute; background: green; height: 50px; width: 50px; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -25px 0 0 -25px; }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

There are even more ways to manage this.